# Why can't strings be mutable in Java and .NET?

Tags: java, .net, string, mutable

Why is it that they decided to make `String` immutable in Java and .NET (and some other languages)? Why didn't they make it mutable?

Comment: Just a note, in .NET `String` is actually mutable internally. [`StringBuilder` in .NET 2.0 mutates a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564906/how-the-stringbuilder-class-is-implemented-does-it-internally-create-new-string). I'll just leave it here.

Comment: Actually .NET strings **are** mutable. And it's not even a heck of a hack.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

According to [Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html), chapter 4, page 73, 2nd edition:

> "There are many good reasons for this: Immutable classes are easier to
>   design, implement, and use than mutable classes. They are less prone
>   to error and are more secure.
>
> [...]
>
> "**Immutable objects are simple.** An immutable object can be in
>   exactly one state, the state in which it was created. If you make sure
>   that all constructors establish class invariants, then it is
>   guaranteed that these invariants will remain true for all time, with
>   no effort on your part.
>
> [...]
>
> **Immutable objects are inherently thread-safe; they require no synchronization.** They cannot be corrupted by multiple threads
>   accessing them concurrently. This is far and away the easiest approach
>   to achieving thread safety. In fact, no thread can ever observe any
>   effect of another thread on an immutable object. Therefore,
>   **immutable objects can be shared freely**
>
> [...]

Other small points from the same chapter:

> Not only can you share immutable objects, but you can share their internals.
>
> [...]
>
> Immutable objects make great building blocks for other objects, whether mutable or immutable.
>
> [...]
>
> The only real disadvantage of immutable classes is that they require a separate object for each distinct value.

Comment: Read the second sentence of my answer:  Immutable classes are easier to design, implement, and use than mutable classes. They are less prone to error and are more secure.

Comment: @PRINCESSFLUFF I would add that sharing mutable strings is dangerous even on a single thread.  For example, copying a report: `report2.Text = report1.Text;`.  Then, somewhere else, modifying the text: `report2.Text.Replace(someWord, someOtherWord);`.  This would change the first report as well as the second.

Comment: @Sam he didn't ask "why they can't be mutable", he asked "why they decided to make immutable" which this answers perfectly.

Comment: @PRINCESSFLUFF This answer doesn't address strings specifically. That was the OPs question. It's so frustrating - this happens all the time on SO and with String immutability questions as well. The answer here talks about general benefits of immutability. So then why aren't all types immutable? Can you please go back and address String?

Comment: @Howiecamp I think it is implicit by the answer that strings could have been mutable (nothing prevents an hypothetical mutable string class from existing). They just decided not to do it that way for simplicity, and because it covered the 99% cases of use. They still provided StringBuilder for the other 1% cases.

Comment: I still don't see an explanation of why not make arrays immutable for the same reasons.

Answer (score 104):

There are at least two reasons.

**First - security** http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article1060.html

> The main reason why String made
>   immutable was security. Look at this
>   example: We have a file open method
>   with login check. We pass a String to
>   this method to process authentication
>   which is necessary before the call
>   will be passed to OS. If String was
>   mutable it was possible somehow to
>   modify its content after the
>   authentication check before OS gets
>   request from program then it is
>   possible to request any file. So if
>   you have a right to open text file in
>   user directory but then on the fly
>   when somehow you manage to change the
>   file name you can request to open
>   "passwd" file or any other. Then a
>   file can be modified and it will be
>   possible to login directly to OS.

**Second - Memory efficiency** http://hikrish.blogspot.com/2006/07/why-string-class-is-immutable.html

> JVM internally maintains the "String
>   Pool". To achive the memory
>   efficiency, JVM will refer the String
>   object from pool. It will not create
>   the new String objects. So, whenever
>   you create a new string literal, JVM
>   will check in the pool whether it
>   already exists or not. If already
>   present in the pool, just give the
>   reference to the same object or create
>   the new object in the pool. There will
>   be many references point to the same
>   String objects, if someone changes the
>   value, it will affect all the
>   references. So, sun decided to make it
>   immutable.

Comment: Its a good point about reuse, and especially true if you use String.intern().  It would have been possible to reuse without making all strings immutable, but life tends to get complicated at that point.

Comment: Neither one of those seem to be terribly valid reasons to me in this day and age.

Comment: i'm not moved by the security reason.  The authentication process can copy the value of the string to a new internal object before the check.

Comment: I'm not too convinced by the memory efficiency argument (i.e., when two or more String objects share the same data, and one is modified, then both get modified). CString objects in MFC get around that by using reference counting.

Comment: security isn't really part of the Raison d'être for immutable strings - your OS will copy strings to kernel-mode buffers and do access-check there, to avoid timing attacks. It's really all about thread safety & performance :)

Comment: I gotta say, the security argument doesn't convince me at all.

Comment: The security argument doesn't make sense. The string is only immutable in that particular language (Java). If it "was possible somehow to modify" the string, it wouldn't be in Java because I consider Java to be very secure - it would be some sort of native exploit.

Comment: The memory efficiency argument doesn't work either. In a native language like C, string constants are simply pointers to data in the initialized data section - they are read-only/immutable anyway. "if someone changes the value" - again, strings from the pool are read-only anyway.

Answer (score 59):

Actually, the reasons string are immutable in java doesn't have much to do with security. The two main reasons are the following:

### Thead Safety:

Strings are extremely widely used type of object. It is therefore more or less guaranteed to be used in a multi-threaded environment. Strings are immutable to make sure that it is safe to share strings among threads. Having an immutable strings ensures that when passing strings from thread A to another thread B, thread B cannot unexpectedly modify thread A's string.

Not only does this help simplify the already pretty complicated task of multi-threaded programming, but it also helps with performance of multi-threaded applications. Access to mutable objects must somehow be synchronized when they can be accessed from multiple threads, to make sure that one thread doesn't attempt to read the value of your object while it is being modified by another thread. Proper synchronization is both hard to do correctly for the programmer, and expensive at runtime. Immutable objects cannot be modified and therefore do not need synchronization.

### Performance:

While String interning has been mentioned, it only represents a small gain in memory efficiency for Java programs. Only string literals are interned. This means that only the strings which are the same in your *source code* will share the same String Object. If your program dynamically creates string that are the same, they will be represented in different objects.

More importantly, immutable strings allow them to share their internal data. For many string operations, this means that the underlying array of characters does not need to be copied. For example, say you want to take the five first characters of String. In Java, you would calls myString.substring(0,5). In this case, what the substring() method does is simply to create a new String object that shares myString's underlying char[] but who knows that it starts at index 0 and ends at index 5 of that char[]. To put this in graphical form, you would end up with the following:

```
 |               myString                  |
 v                                         v
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"   <-- shared char[]
 ^   ^
 |   |  myString.substring(0,5)
```

This makes this kind of operations extremely cheap, and O(1) since the operation neither depends on the length of the original string, nor on the length of the substring we need to extract. This behavior also has some memory benefits, since many strings can share their underlying char[].

Comment: Implementing substrings as references that share the underlying `char[]` is a rather questionable design decision. If you read in a whole file into a single string and maintain a reference to just a 1-character substring, the whole file will have to be kept in memory.

Comment: Exactly, I ran into that particular gotcha while creating a website crawler that only needed to extract a few words from the whole page. The whole page HTML code was in memory, and due to substring sharing the char[], I kept the whole HTML code even though I only needed a few bytes. A workaround for that is to use new String(original.substring(..,..)), the String(String) constructor makes a copy of the relevant range of the underlying array.

Comment: An addendum to cover subsequent changes: Since Jave 7, `String.substring()` performs a full copy, in order to prevent the problems mentioned in comments above. In Java 8, the two fields enabling `char[]` sharing, namely `count` and `offset`, are removed, thus reducing memory footprint of String instances.

Comment: I agree with Thead Safety part, but doubt substring case.

Comment: @LoveRight: Then check the source code of java.lang.String (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java), it's been like that all the way until Java 6 (which was current when this answer was written). I has apparently changed in Java 7.

Answer (score 32):

Thread safety and performance. If a string cannot be modified it is safe and quick to pass a reference around among multiple threads. If strings were mutable, you would always have to copy all of the bytes of the string to a new instance, or provide synchronization. A typical application will read a string 100 times for every time that string needs to be modified. See wikipedia on [immutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Answer (score 11):

One should really ask, "why should X be mutable?" It's better to default to immutability, because of the benefits already mentioned by [Princess Fluff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-string-be-not-immutable-in-java-and-net/93216#93216). It should be an exception that something is mutable.

Unfortunately most of the current programming languages default to mutability, but hopefully in the future the default is more on immutablity (see [A Wish List for the Next Mainstream Programming Language](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2008/12/29/a-wish-list-for-the-next-mainstream-programming-language)).

Answer (score 8):

`String` is not a primitive type, yet you normally want to use it with value semantics, i.e. like a value.

A value is something you can trust won't change behind your back.
If you write: `String str = someExpr();`
You don't want it to change unless YOU do something with `str`.

`String` as an `Object` has naturally pointer semantics, to get value semantics as well it needs to be immutable.

Answer (score 8):

Wow! I Can't believe the misinformation here. `String`s being immutable have nothing with security. If someone already has access to the objects in a running application (which would have to be assumed if you are trying to guard against someone 'hacking' a `String` in your app), they would certainly be a plenty of other opportunities available for hacking.

It's a quite novel idea that the immutability of `String` is addressing threading issues. Hmmm ... I have an object that is being changed by two different threads. How do I resolve this? synchronize access to the object? Naawww ... let's not let anyone change the object at all -- that'll fix all of our messy concurrency issues! In fact, let's make all objects immutable, and then we can removed the synchonized contruct from the Java language.

The real reason (pointed out by others above) is memory optimization. It is quite common in any application for the same string literal to be used repeatedly. It is so common, in fact, that decades ago, many compilers made the optimization of storing only a single instance of a `String` literal. The drawback of this optimization is that runtime code that modifies a `String` literal introduces a problem because it is modifying the instance for all other code that shares it. For example, it would be not good for a function somewhere in an application to change the `String` literal `"dog"` to `"cat"`. A `printf("dog")` would result in `"cat"` being written to stdout. For that reason, there needed to be a way of guarding against code that attempts to change `String` literals (i. e., make them immutable). Some compilers (with support from the OS) would accomplish this by placing `String` literal into a special readonly memory segment that would cause a memory fault if a write attempt was made.

In Java this is known as interning. The Java compiler here is just following an standard memory optimization done by compilers for decades. And to address the same issue of these `String` literals being modified at runtime, Java simply makes the `String` class immutable (i. e, gives you no setters that would allow you to change the `String` content). `String`s would not have to be immutable if interning of `String` literals did not occur.

Comment: I strongly disagree about immutability and threading comment, it seems to me you're not quite getting the point there. And if Josh Bloch, one of Java implementers, says that was the one of the design issues, how can that be misinformation?

Comment: Synchronization is expensive.  References to mutable objects need to be synchronized, not so for immutable.  That's a reason to make all objects immutable unless they have to be mutable.  Strings can be immutable, and therefore doing that makes them more efficient in multiple threads.

Comment: @Jim: Memory optimization is not 'THE' reason, it's 'A' reason.  Thread-safety is also 'A' reason, because immutable objects are inherently thread-safe and require no expensive synchronization, as David mentioned.  Thread safety is actually a side-effect of an object being immutable.  You can think of synchronization as a way to make the object "temporarily" immutable (ReaderWriterLock will make it read-only, and a regular lock will make it inaccessible altogether, which of course makes it immutable as well).

Comment: @DavidThornley: The creation of multiple independent reference paths to a mutable value holder effectively turns it into an entity, and makes it much harder to reason about even aside from threading issues.  Generally, mutable objects are more efficient that immutable ones in cases where exactly one reference path will exist to each, but immutable objects allow objects' contents to be shared efficiently by sharing references.  The best pattern is exemplified by `String` and `StringBuffer`, but unfortunately few other types follow that model.

Answer (score 7):

One factor is that, if `String`s were mutable, objects storing `String`s would have to be careful to store copies, lest their internal data change without notice. Given that `String`s are a fairly primitive type like numbers, it is nice when one can treat them as if they were passed by value, even if they are passed by reference (which also helps to save on memory).

Comment: Strings are not "fairly primitive types" as you make them out to be; primitives can be cheaply copied, cheaply compared, cheaply stored, cannot be `null`, and are highly optimized by the compiler. `String`s are none of those things.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bump, but...
Are they really immutable?
Consider the following.

```
public static unsafe void MutableReplaceIndex(string s, char c, int i)
{
    fixed (char* ptr = s)
    {
        *((char*)(ptr + i)) = c;
    }
}
```

...

```
string s = "abc";
MutableReplaceIndex(s, '1', 0);
MutableReplaceIndex(s, '2', 1);
MutableReplaceIndex(s, '3', 2);
Console.WriteLine(s); // Prints 1 2 3
```

You could even make it an extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static unsafe void MutableReplaceIndex(this string s, char c, int i)
    {
        fixed (char* ptr = s)
        {
            *((char*)(ptr + i)) = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Which makes the following work

```
s.MutableReplaceIndex('1', 0);
s.MutableReplaceIndex('2', 1);
s.MutableReplaceIndex('3', 2);
```

Conclusion: They're in an immutable state which is known by the compiler. Of couse the above only applies to .NET strings as Java doesn't have pointers. However a string can be entirely mutable using pointers in C#. It's not how pointers are intended to be used, has practical usage or is safely used; it's however possible, thus bending the whole "mutable" rule. You can normally not modify an index directly of a string and this is the only way. There is a way that this could be prevented by disallowing pointer instances of strings or making a copy when a string is pointed to, but neither is done, which makes strings in C# not entirely immutable.

Comment: +1. .NET strings are not really immutable; in fact, this is done all the time in the String and StringBuilder classes for perf reasons.

Answer (score 3):

For most purposes, a "string" is (used/treated as/thought of/assumed to be) a meaningful **atomic unit,** *just like a number*.

### Asking why the individual characters of a string are not mutable is therefore like asking why the individual bits of an integer are not mutable.

You should know why.  Just think about it.

I hate to say it, but unfortunately we're debating this because our language sucks, and we're trying to using a single word, ***string***, to describe a complex, contextually situated concept or class of object.

We perform calculations and comparisons with "strings" similar to how we do with numbers.  If strings (or integers) were mutable, we'd have to write special code to lock their values into immutable local forms in order to perform any kind of calculation reliably.  Therefore, it is best to think of a string like a numeric identifier, but instead of being 16, 32, or 64 bits long, it could be hundreds of bits long.

When someone says "string", we all think of different things.  Those who think of it simply as a set of characters, with no particular purpose in mind, will of course be appalled that someone *just decided* that they should not be able to manipulate those characters.  But the "string" class isn't just an array of characters.  It's a `STRING`, not a `char[]`.  There are some basic assumptions about the concept we refer to as a "string", and it generally can be described as meaningful, atomic unit of coded data like a number.  When people talk about "manipulating strings", perhaps they're really talking about manipulating **characters** to build **strings**, and a StringBuilder is great for that.  Just think a bit about what the word "string" truly means.

Consider for a moment what it would be like if strings were mutable.  The following API function could be tricked into returning information for a different user if the *mutable* username string is intentionally or unintentionally modified by another thread while this function is using it:

```
string GetPersonalInfo( string username, string password )
{
    string stored_password = DBQuery.GetPasswordFor( username );
    if (password == stored_password)
    {
        //another thread modifies the mutable 'username' string
        return DBQuery.GetPersonalInfoFor( username );
    }
}
```

Security isn't just about 'access control', it's also about 'safety' and 'guaranteeing correctness'.  If a method can't be easily written and depended upon to perform a simple calculation or comparison reliably, then it's not safe to call it, but it would be safe to call into question the programming language itself.

Comment: In C#, a string is mutable by its pointer (use `unsafe`) or simply through reflection (you can get the underlying field easily). This makes the point on security void, as anybody that *intentionally* wants to change a string, can do so quite easily. However, it provides security to programmers: unless you do something special, the string is guaranteed immutable (but it's not threadsafe!).

Comment: Yes, you can change the bytes of any data object (string, int, etc.) through pointers. However, we're talking about why the string class is immutable in the sense that it has no public methods built into it for modifying its characters. I was saying that a string is a lot like a number in that manipulating individual characters makes no more sense than manipulating individual bits of a number (when you treat a string as a whole token (not as a byte array), and a number as a numeric value (not as a bit field). We're talking at the conceptual object level, not at the sub-object level.

Comment: And just to clarify, pointers in object-oriented code are inherently unsafe, exactly because they circumvent the public interfaces defined for a class. What I was saying, was that a function could be easily tricked if the public interface for a string allowed it to be modified by other threads. Of course, it can always be tricked by accessing data directly with pointers, but not as easily or unintentionally.

Comment: 'pointers in object-oriented code are inherently unsafe' unless you call them *references*. References in Java are not different to pointers in C++ (only pointer arithmetic is disabled). A different concept is memory management that can be managed or manual, but that is a different thing. You could have reference semantics (pointers with no arithmetic) without having GC (the opposite would be harder in the sense that the semantics of reachability would be harder to make clean, but not unfeasable)

Comment: The other thing is that if strings are *almost* immutable, but not quite so, (I don't know enough CLI here), that can be really bad for security reasons. In some older Java implementations you could do that, and I found a snippet of code that used that to *internalize* strings (try to locate other internal string that has the same value, share the pointer, remove the old memory block) and used the backdoor to rewrite the string contents forcing an incorrect behavior in a different class. (Consider rewriting "SELECT *" to "DELETE ")

Answer (score 3):

Immutability is not so closely tied to security. For that, at least in .NET, you get the `SecureString` class.

Later edit: In Java you will find `GuardedString`, a similar implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a trade off. `String`s go into the `String` pool and when you create multiple identical `String`s they share the same memory. The designers figured this memory saving technique would work well for the common case, since programs tend to grind over the same strings a lot.

The downside is that concatenations make a lot of extra `String`s that are only transitional and just become garbage, actually harming memory performance. You have `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` (in Java, `StringBuilder` is also in .NET) to use to preserve memory in these cases.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "string pool" is not automatically used for _ALL_ strings unless you explicitly use "inter()"'ed strings.

Answer (score 2):

The decision to have string mutable in C++ causes a lot of problems, see this excellent article by Kelvin Henney about [Mad COW Disease](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403779).

COW = Copy On Write.

Answer (score 2):

`String`s in Java are not truly immutable, you can change their value's using reflection and or class loading. You should not be depending on that property for security.
For examples see: [Magic Trick In Java](http://blogs.atlassian.com/developer/2008/07/magic_trick_in_java.html)

Comment: I believe that you will only be able to do such tricks if your code is running with full trust, therefore there is no security loss. You could as well use JNI to write directly on the memory location where the strings are stored.

Comment: Actually I believe you can change any immutable object by reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Immutability is good. See Effective Java. If you had to copy a String every time you passed it around, then that would be a lot of error-prone code. You also have confusion as to which modifications affect which references. In the same way that Integer has to be immutable to behave like int, Strings have to behave as immutable to act like primitives. In C++ passing strings by value does this without explicit mention in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception for nearly almost every rule:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Guess
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string str = "ABC";

            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.WriteLine(str.GetHashCode());

            var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(str, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            try
            {
                Marshal.WriteInt16(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 4, 'Z');

                Console.WriteLine(str);
                Console.WriteLine(str.GetHashCode());
            }
            finally
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's largely for security reasons.  It's much harder to secure a system if you can't trust that your `String`s are tamperproof.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "tamperproof". This answers feels really out of context.

Comment: By your logic, there should never be any mutability _at all_, because "It's much harder to secure a system if you can't trust that your `Object`s are tamperproof"