# How many people have been stung by Java substring memory issues?

Tags: java, substring

I recently discovered that the java.lang.String.substring method does not return a new string, but a view of the original string that was substringed.  This can have memory implications.  For example, if you're reading an ascii file, and parsing tokens in the file using substring and storing the result of substring in memory somewhere -- what you're actually storing in memory is the entire string prior to the substring operation!  You can of course solve this by wrapping substring in your own version that returns a new string of the subtring result.

Comment: If you take more than one substring of the same string you can actually save memory. ;)

Comment: Actually, this changed in some update of Java 7. Now substrings are copies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been bitten by it once, reading a dictionary file line by line. Each line was very short, but the buffer created by `BufferedReader` meant that each string was backed by an 80-char array.

That was when I first learned the point of writing:

```
word = new String(word);
```

Most of the time it's not a problem though - and of course it *can* be more efficient than the "take a completely separate copy" approach.

Comment: more computationally efficient, yes.

Comment: And potentially more efficient in memory too - if you still need the original string, or potentially many overlapping substrings.

Answer (score 1):

In the year 2000 or 2001, one of the early `XML` parsers (I can't remember which) suffered from this problem. It took us a while to track down how we were going out of memory by reading about 3 fields out of some early `FpML` (very big `XML` documents which describe financial products).

What is really annoying is that if a write

```
String copy = new String(s);
```

IntelliJ IDEA warns me that this is redundant! Stupid IDE.

Comment: Sounds like somebody over at JetBrains needs to read up on String interning

Answer (score 0):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

In the java docs, it states that the substring method does return a new string.

Or did I misunderstand the question?

Also, strings are immutable.  [Here's a SO thread that explains why that is so.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-string-be-mutable-in-java-and-net)

Comment: it's a new string object, but the underlying data can be shared