# string class Replace and Stringbuilder replace

Tags: c#

```
string s = "value_test_this";
string m = s.Replace('e','E');

StringBuilder strBuilder  = new StringBuilder("value_test_this");
strBuilder.Replace('e','E');
```

since strings are immutable, how does the `Replace` works in string class,

Comment: Check this post will explain the things to you which you want [Why to use StringBuilder over string to get better performance](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/02/why-to-user-stringbuilder-over-string.html)

Answer (score 5):

It creates another string in the memory and then points the `m` to that new string. The old string also stays in the memory.

And that is exactly why `StringBuilder` should be used if frequent modifications have to be made to the string.

If you want to know why Strings are immutable in C#, look at [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

Comment: This is wrong - `s` is definitely *not* pointed to the new string. The `Replace` method, along with many other string methods, creates a brand new string based on some logic, and returns this new string. `s` remains unchanged. The variable `m` is a reference to the new string. You need to replace `s` with `m` in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a string.Replace it's simply going to create a new string (since, as you said, it is immutable). In StringBuilder there's no new string being created, the one you have gets modified.