# C# reference question

Tags: c#

Why does **b.b** would not change to "a2" as with f.f?

Thanks.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo f = new Foo
        {
            f = getStr()
        };

        Boo b = new Boo
        {
            b = f.f
        };


        f.f = "a2";

        Console.WriteLine(f.f);
        Console.WriteLine(b.b);
    }

    public static string getStr()
    {
        string a = "a1";
        return a;
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string f { get; set; }
}

public class Boo
{
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in .NET is immutable, that means, you are not sending the reference, but the value.

In other classes in .NET, you are passing references. Like this:

```
Car c = new Car();
c.Name = "Ford";
var d = c;
d.Name = "Volvo";
c.Name; //Volvo
```

but in string, it is working like this:

```
string s = "Hey";
string c = s;
c = "World!";
//s is still "Hey"
```

Look at this question for more information: [Why .NET String is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

It is, of course, the same with other classes.

```
Car c = new Car();
c.Name = "Ford";
Car d = c;
//d.Name == "Ford";
d = new Car();
d.Name = "Volvo";
//c.Name is still "Ford"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler piece of code demonstrating what I think you're expecting to see:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = x;
x = "there";
```

You appear to expect `y` to be `"there"` at this point. But `x` and `y` are entirely independent variables - the assignment in the second merely copies the value of `x` (a reference to a string "hello") to `y`. The third line assigns a *different* value to `x` (a reference to a string "there") - it doesn't change the value of `y`, which is still a referent to a string "hello".

Your example is more complicated as it's using separate types with automatically implemented properties - but the fundamental concepts are the same.

Answer (score 1):

`Boo.b` and `Foo.f` are strings, not pointers to strings.
Assigning `Foo.f` to `Boo.b` assigns the value of `Foo.f` to `Boo.b`. After that assignment, they are independent. Changing `Foo.f` will not change `Boo.b`.

Comment: Actually Boo.b and Foo.F _are_ references (pointers) to strings.

Comment: Not in the sense the OP thinks, that's why I wasn't using that word but the word "pointer" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it? You're not changing it. Just because you set b.b to f.f in the past, doesn't mean it'll keep udpating it with any changes.

You set a value, not a reference.