# Padding a string using PadRight method

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am trying to add spaces to end of a string in C#:

```
Trip_Name1.PadRight(20);
```

Also tried:

```
Trip_Name1.PadRight(20,' ');
```

None of this seems to work. However I can pad the string with any other character. Why?

I should have been more specific, here is full code:

```
lnk_showmatch_1.Text = u_trip.Trip_Name1.PadRight(20,' ');
```

Comment: What is `Trip_Name1` in your tests? What is the return value of those methods (i.e. what does *"doesn't seem to work"* mean)? And you're aware that these methods won't modify the value of `Trip_Name1`, right?

Comment: Can you provide the code sample? By the way, strings are immutable and you have to reassign the result value after padding

Comment: I should have been more specific, here is full code:

lnk_showmatch_1.Text = u_trip.Trip_Name1.PadRight(20,' ');

Answer (score 29, accepted):

String are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), they cannot be changed. `PadRight` returns a new instance of the string padded, not change the one it was called from. What you want is this:

```
Trip_Name1 = Trip_Name1.PadRight(20,' ');
```

There is a great discussion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable) StackOverflow question as to why strings are immutable.

**EDIT**:

> None of this seems to work. However I can pad the string with any other character.

Are you actually re-assigning it like the example above? If that is the case - then without more detail I can only think of the following:

1. If you are storing this in a database and retrieving it, some databases with the correct settings may "Trim" for you.
2. You have logic somewhere else that is trimming the white-spaces. This is common when dealing with user input.

**EDIT 2**:

> I should have been more specific

I'm going to take a wild guess based on your naming conventions that you are dealing with HTML / ASP.NET. In most cases, in HTML - [white space is collapsed](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html). For example:

```
<div><a>Hello           World</a></div>
<div><a>Hello World</a></div>
```

Both of the `a` tags will render the same because the white-space is being collapsed. If you are indeed working with HTML - that is likely your reason and why the padding works for all other characters. If you do a view-source of the markup rendered - does it contain the additional white spaces?

If you wanted to keep the whitespaces, try applying a CSS style on your element called `white-space` and set it to `pre`. For example:

```
<a style="white-space:pre">hello     world      </a>
```

That will cause the white-space to be preserved. Keep in mind that using white space like this has disadvantages. Browsers don't render them identically, etc. I wouldn't use this for layout purposes. Consider using CSS and something like `min-width` instead.

Comment: @user554134 - I've made a few more edits based on your update.

Comment: Does not work for me too. Same problem                                              var str = INRECField.PadRight(11, ' ') +
                      INRECDate?.ToString("MMddyy") +
                      INRECModel.PadRight(12, ' ') +
                      INRECSerial.PadRight(14, ' ') +
                      INRECAccessCode.PadRight(5, ' ');

            str = str.PadRight(32, ' ');

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind, that way won't work for any string manipulation functionality because string is immutable. They just return a new string rather than updating the existing instance.

> [PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx) returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in
>   this string by padding them on the right with a specified Unicode
>   character, for a specified total length.

```
string Trip_Name1 = Trip_Name1.PadRight(20,' ');
```

EDIT:

Your control seems to be trimming the ending spaces. So, try to set the padding for the control rather than for the text.