# C# Delete the nth item from a string

Tags: c#, .net

How would i go about deleting (not just replacing with a `' '`) The nth char of a string. Say i want to have `Hello World` output `Hllo World` any thing that could do this?

Comment: Two substrings (one of all characters before the one you wish to delete, the other of characters after) and then you concatenate them.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Replacing a char at a given index in string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9367119/299327)

Comment: check out my answer its better and cooler and youll look cooler using linq than with using the built in String.Remove function ;)

Comment: @jordan.peoples: Your approach is clumsier and slower than the builtin `String.Remove`. Ryan, that is not a duplicate. How could a question "not replacing in string" be a duplicate of "replacing char in string"?

Comment: there's no way its slower. may take more space and more screen real estate, but looks cooler and is more flexible for a wider range of applications @TimSchmelter Also, try to keep it professional.  saying "Are you kidding?" gets a flagged comment.

Comment: @jordan.peoples: Removed the "kidding" but again, looks cooler is no value and multiple lines that create many intermediate strings instead of one efficient method is not _cooler_ but just redundant.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Possibilities my dear tim, possibilities.

Comment: @jordan.peoples: You can downvote all of my answers and questions if you want, that won't make your answer more useful at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter who down voted what now? i got a down vote for my awesome answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Don't worry, he went on a downvote campaign against me recently after he complained about downvotes on a horrible answer.  A few days later they were all reversed.  It's not worth arguing with him.  He won't see sense and he gets childishly defensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With .Remove

```
var removed = s.Remove(1, 1);
```

note,  you can't change a string, you can only create a new string with the character removed.

Answer (score 2):

String class has a [remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) method

```
var s = "abc".Remove(1,1); //will return ac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("Hello World");
a.remove(1, 1);
```