# "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'"

Tags: c#

I have searched this site for similar questions and the ones I've found don't work for me. I apologize for asking if the answer is somewhere and I haven't been able to find it. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong by asking this.

I am making hangman in C#. What I've done is make it so that the program picks a random string from an array, makes an array of the guessed letters (which it initially fills with '_' for as long as the word is). It then is supposed to get a user's input for a letter, see if that letter is in the word, and if it is, add that letter to the guessed letters array. I am stuck at this part:

```
if (gameWord.Contains(guessedLetter)) 
{
    //for every character in gameWord
    for (int x = 0; x < gameWord.Length; x++)
    {
        //if the character at the 'x' position in gameWord is equal to the guessed letter
        if (gameWord[x] == guessedLetter)
        {
            //guessString at that x position is equal to the guessed letter
            guessString[x] = guessedLetter;
        }
    }

}
```

At "`if (gameWord[x] == guessedLetter)`" I am getting the error  shown in the title.

gameWord is a string chosen from an array of strings, and guessedLetter is a string inputted by the user with `Console.ReadLine();`.

Comment: Convert the string to a char or the char to a string.

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining your problem and showing the code. Good job!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I apologize John, I won't do that next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `guessedLetter` is a `string`, then you need to change one type to the other. You could easily just get the first character of `guessedLetter`:

```
if (gameWord[x] == guessedLetter[0])
```

or call `ToString()` on `gameWord[x]` as the other answer suggests.

However, you are about to run into a *much* bigger problem. [] is a readonly operation ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)) since strings are immutable, so your next line (the assignment) will fail.

To do that, you'll need a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(gameWord);
sb[index] = guessedLetter[0];
gameWord = sb.ToString();
```

Credit to [Replacing a char at a given index in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367119/replacing-a-char-at-a-given-index-in-string) for that code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare values of the same type. When taking a character from gameWord, i.e. **gameWord[x]**, that value is treated as a *char*.

**guessedLetter** also needs to be of type *char* in order for the comparison to work.

I am assuming that guessedLetter is of type *string* here.

Here is an example:

```
string gameWord = "Random"; 
char guessedLetter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i=0; i < gameWord.length; i++) {
    if (gameWord[i] == guessedLetter)
        Console.WriteLine("Letter was found!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

gameWord[x] is accessing a character of gameWord, so it's a character, not a string. You can convert it to string before comparison:

```
if (gameWord[x].ToString() == guessedLetter)
```