# Replacing specific parts of a string in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm pretty familiar with finding and replacing things in an array, but I'm having trouble finding out how to replace specific parts of a string. For instance, say the first item in my array is a string of sixteen random numbers like 1786549809654768. How would I go about replacing the first twelve characters with x's for example?

Comment: See Jon Skeet's answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9367156/225600.

Answer (score 2):

Because `string` can be translated to and from an array of `char` you could easily transform your problem into *replace things in an array* problem:

```
char[] characters = input.ToCharArray();

// do your replace logic here

string result = new string(characters);
```

Or you could use `Substring`. Assuming `n` is number of characters you want to replace from the beginning or the string:

```
string result = new string('x', n) + input.Substring(n);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I was pretty stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq:

```
String test = "1234123412341234";
string output = new String(test.Select((c, index) => index < 12 ? 'x' : c).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(output);
//xxxxxxxxxxxx1234
```