# C# Getting value between two same characters

Tags: c#, regex, character

Usually, we can easily get a String value between two characters. My question is, how do I get the **value between two *same* characters**.

For example:

```
String full_value = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367119/title-goes-here";
```

In this example, how can I extract the value `9367119` from the entire string?

The solution that I use doesn't work since `9367119` has the same `/` characters to the right and left of it.

**Here's what I have so far:**

This works for values that doesn't have two same characters to the left and right. Such as: /dog\ I can easily replace `/` and `\` with my solution

```
public static string Between(string full_value, string a, string b)
{
        int posA = full_value.IndexOf(a);
        int posB = full_value.LastIndexOf(b);
        if (posA == -1)
        {
            return "";
        }
        if (posB == -1)
        {
            return "";
        }
        int adjustedPosA = posA + a.Length;
        if (adjustedPosA >= posB)
        {
            return "";
        }
        return full_value.Substring(adjustedPosA, posB - adjustedPosA);
    }
```

Comment: why don't you split the string based on the `/` separator and get the penultimate slice?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understood what you meant? @fedorqui

Comment: Please redefine your requirements. It does not confirm to your example. Your example should be returning a string array of `stackoverflow.com`, `questions` and `9367119`.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at _Uri.Segments_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) and get the relevant part:

```
string s = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367119/title-goes-here";
string[] sp = s.Split('/');
Console.WriteLine(sp[4]);
```

[IdeOne demo](https://ideone.com/nV4jut).

Comment: Yes ended up coding the same thing after @fedorqui's comment. Thanks! I will accept this in a bit

Comment: Thanks I didn't see the comment till I post the solution.

Comment: Maybe `s.Split(new[] {"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(m => m.All(p => Char.IsDigit(p))).FirstOrDefault()`? You won't have to check if the all-digit chunk is the 5th element in the string. Unless you know it will always be there.

Answer (score 1):

Use following regex:

```
(?<=/)\d+(?=/)

String full_value = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367119/title-goes-here";
var matches = Regex.Matches(full_value, @"(?<=/)\d+(?=/)");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 string s = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367119/title-goes-here";
    string[] sps = s.Split('/');
    foreach(string sp in sps ){
     if(sp =="9367119"){
       Console.WriteLine(sp);
      }
    }
```