# How to remove and place a single character in a string?

Tags: c#, string

Here's my string: `String s = "X0001";`

Now I want to replace `X` with `N`.

i.e
`String s = "N0001;`

How can I do this?

Comment: What programming language is the referring to?

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: see the question.updated with c# lang

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987141/how-to-change-1-char-in-the-string

Comment: I think you must search a little bit more on stack before doing this question. The String.Replace will help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
String s = "X0001";
s = s.Replace('X', 'N');
```

With this, `Console.WriteLine(s)` will output

> N0001

Comment: @thomas.now s contains only N.i want s=N0001

Comment: @iDontKnow Fixed. Error cause: not enough coffee

Comment: sorry...Replace N with X;s="X0001" replace with s="N0001"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all, use `String.Replace`:

```
s = s.Replace("X", "N");
```

If you want to replace the first;

```
s = "N" + s.Substring(1);
```

If you have something like `<xml><Name>X0001</Name>` and you want to replace X0001 with N0001 you *can* use string methods ( or XML libraries):

```
string xml = "<xml><Name>X0001</Name>";
int start = xml.IndexOf("<Name>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
if (start >= 0)
{
    start += "<Name>".Length;
    int end = xml.IndexOf("</Name>", start, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    if (end >= 0)
    {
        string before = xml.Substring(0, start);
        string token = xml.Substring(start, end - start);
        string after = xml.Substring(end);
        if (token.Length > 0)
            xml = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
                before, 
                token.Replace("X", "N"), 
                after);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Tim..if for example the String in XML like <xml><Name>X0001</Name>..in this situation how can i cahnge X0001 to N0001...pls give me reply

Comment: @iDontKnow: so now your input changes to `<xml><Name>X0001</Name>`? Are you sure that the next question won't be "how to modify the xml file"?

Comment: @iDontKnow: have a look.

Comment: @iDontKnow, I think you need 200K rep to parse XML with `string.IndexOf`... :) And 600K to use regular expression to do that... Please use `XDocument` to deal with XML...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: i didn't want to deviate from the original question too much which was about a single string. Now it seems to be still a single string which is a little bit longer. If it's getting a whole xml file OP should ask a different question.