# Replacing backslash in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am having a few problems with trying to replace backslashes in a date string on C# .net.

So far I am using:

```
string.Replace(@"\","-")
```

but it hasnt done the replacement. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Are you sure the string contains backslashes and not _forward_ slashes (as _dates_ are mostly represented)?

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off formatting a `DateTime` than trying to do string manipulation.

Comment: Sorry oded, its whatever the one in my example is?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`string.Replace` does not modify the string itself but returns a new string, which most likely you are throwing away. Do this instead:

```
myString= myString.Replace(@"\","-");
```

On a side note, this kind of operation is usually seen in code that manually mucks around with formatted date strings. Most of the time there is a better way to do what you want (which is?) than things like this.

Answer (score 5):

as all of them saying you need to take value back in the variable.

so it should be

```
 val1= val1.Replace(@"\","-");
```

Or

```
 val1= val1.Replace("\\","-");
```

but not only .. below one will not work

```
 val1.Replace(@"\","-");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it this way.

```
oldstring = oldstring.Replace(@"\","-");
```

Look for `String.Replace` return type.

Its a function which returns a corrected string. If it would have simply changed old string then it would had a `void` return type.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
myString = myString.Replace('\\', '-'));
```

but just letting you know, date slashes are usually forward ones `/`, and not backslashes `\`.

Comment: `"\\" == @"\"` no? I don't suposse limiting to `char` will make the difference either.

Comment: @ericosg: Read about `verbatim strings in C#`

Comment: @Jodrell, thanks, yes they are the same, was just proposing an alternative whilst more important to note the forward slash. i've edited it too.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others that String.Replace doesn't update the original string object but it returns a new string instead.

```
myString= myString.Replace(@"\","-");
```

It's worthwhile for you to understand that string is immutable in C# basically to make it thread-safe. More details about strings and why they are immutable please see links [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)