# How can I produce JSON without strangely slash character by JsonSerializer?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

The `JsonSerializer` I am using is `System.Text.Json;` in .net core 3.1

Here are two projects, one is project A, the other is project B.

Here is the code of project A:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {            
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Get")]
        public async Task<string> Get()
        {
            Models.TestModel TestModel = new Models.TestModel() { Success = "1" };            
            string Content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(TestModel, typeof(Models.TestModel), new JsonSerializerOptions() { Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.Create(System.Text.Unicode.UnicodeRanges.All) });            
            return Content;
        }                      
    }
}
```

And here is the code of project B:

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    [Route("api/")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
        public TestController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("TestGet")]
        public async Task TestGet()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                string.Format("https://localhost:44345/api/Get"));

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            string Content = "";
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Models.TestModel TestModel = new Models.TestModel();
                TestModel = (Models.TestModel)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Content, typeof(Models.TestModel));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both of them using the same model:

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public string Success { get; set; } = "";
        public string SuccessRemark { get; set; } = "";
    }
```

Now the problem is the project A will always produce JSON contains by strangely character '\'.

For example, the right JSON is

```
{"Success":"1","SuccessRemark":""}
```

And it will be turn out to be this:

```
"{\"Success\":\"1\",\"SuccessRemark\":\"\"}"
```

This strange character '\' makes project B can not be deserialized rightly.

I have considered by using a replacing method to remove the character '\'.

I followed all the answers in [Replacing backslash in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752852/replacing-backslash-in-a-string) to remove the character '\'. Meanwhile, none works.

I knew another way to produce json without strangely character '\':

```
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Get")]
        public async Task<Models.TestModel> Get()
        {
            Models.TestModel TestModel = new Models.TestModel() { Success = "1" };            
            return TestModel;
        }
```

Well, in this way only can return a static model while:
I need to return a success model if all codes run successfully.
I need to return an error model if code runs with an error.
This way can not solve this.
Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: isn’t that because you are returning a string where you should return JSON? Your first class correctly returns a string which would escape the “, make sure it returns proper JSON if thats what you want by returning a JObject for example

Comment: @MattDouhan I always consider JSON and string is the same thing while now I am not sure about this.

Comment: A string that contains JSON will need to be **escaped**. So the backslashes are correct. You should return an object, which ASP.NET should convert to JSON for you.

Comment: Very similar to [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182) - you are returning a serialized JSON string, which in turn gets serialized as a JSON string literal a second time.  Return the actual model instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
try
        {
            if (success)
                return Json(new TestModel() { Success = "1" });
            else
                return Json(new TestModel() { Success = "0", SuccessRemark = "error" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new TestModel() { Success = "0", SuccessRemark = ex.Message });
        }
```

Comment: My pleasure. :)