# ToUpper() method not working

Tags: c#, .net

I am passing a message from a server that gets stored into a string variable called strObject. I wish to convert the string inside strObject to upper case. So, I use ToUpper() method. But, when I add a breakpoint and go through the line, my string is not getting converted into Upper case. strObject variable will always contain the text Task_status. I wish to convert it into TASK_STATUS. Am I missing anything? Posting my relevant code below:-

```
public void VerifyValue(String strObject, String strValue, int row)
        {               
            strObject.ToUpper().Trim();
            strValue.ToUpper().Trim();
            switch (strObject)
            {
                case "TASK_STATUS":
                    if (m_taskStatus.taskStatus.ToString() == strValue)
                    {
                        ExcelRecorder(null, row);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ExcelRecorder("The value [" + m_taskStatus.taskStatus.ToString() + "] does not match with the given value.", row);
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: .NET strings are not mutable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strObject.ToUpper()` returns a `string` in upper case

Use the following ...

```
strObject = strObject.ToUpper().Trim();
```

Comment: ya ya...my answer accept button will work only after 6 mins..am waiting to accept ur ans only

Answer (score 6):

A `System.String` is immutable, so you must re-assign, like:

```
strObject = strObject.ToUpper().Trim();
```

All methods that manipulate strings, leave the original string unchanged and returns a **new** string with the desired content. You must pick up that return value and assign it to something.

Answer (score 2):

`string.ToUpper()` returns a value, use it.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, so calling the functions on the string doesn't actually change the strings. Instead they return a modified copy of the strings.

This means that you have to store the returned value of the functions, fore example in the original variable.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work since strings are immutable, you have to assign the value back to `strObject`

```
strObject = strObject.ToUpper().Trim();
```

Also there is nothing much done by the `switch` as shown in your code, you can remove it unless this is not the entire code.

```
public void VerifyValue(String strObject, String strValue, int row)
{               
     //strObject.ToUpper().Trim();
     //strValue.ToUpper().Trim();
     if(strObject.ToUpper() ==  "TASK_STATUS")
     {
          if (m_taskStatus.taskStatus.ToString() == strValue.ToUpper())
          {
              ExcelRecorder(null, row);
          }
          else
          {
               ExcelRecorder("The value [" + m_taskStatus.taskStatus.ToString() + "] does not match with the given value.", row);
           }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Strings are immutable, you need to remember that when you work with them.

Your method inserts values to your strObject and strValue variables to which you call various worker methods but those worker methods do not change the immutable string variables that have already been created.

Although the original variables are immutable you can still set new variables (Even with the same name) equal to the original plus the result of the worker method.

So all you really need to do is to change

`strObject.ToUpper().Trim();`

and

`strValue.ToUpper().Trim();`

to

`strObject = strObject.ToUpper().Trim()`

and

`strValue = strvalue.ToUpper().Trim()`

This answer is pretty much a duplicate of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583601/datetime-adddays-not-working-as-expected/52719465#52719465) but I think both are correct.