# DateTime.AddDays() not working as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I have this simple program:

```
        DateTime aux = new DateTime(2012, 6, 12, 12, 24, 0);
        DateTime aux2 = new DateTime(2012, 6, 12, 13, 24, 0);
        aux2.AddDays(1);

       Console.WriteLine((aux2 - aux).TotalHours.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I debugged this and found `aux2.AddDays(1);` doesn't seem to work, what am I missing here?
it should return 25 but the answer is one.

What is the problem?

also `AddHours` doesn't work, I guess that the others aren't working too.

Comment: `DateTime` instances are immutable.  You have to assign the result of `.AddDays` to another instance (or to itself).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It does work but you don't do anything with the return value, try

```
aux2 = aux2.AddDays(1);
```

`DateTime`s share this facet of immutability with `String`s.

---

**EDIT**

There is a little paragraph about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

> This method does not change the value of this DateTime. Instead, it
>   returns a new DateTime whose value is the result of this operation.

Comment: seriously :| , i am out of words, i thought that aux2 will change automatically and that this is a bug.

Comment: yes, "Returns a new DateTime string ..."", tool tip on mouse over

Comment: @SasGabriel, note that tooltip/docs in .NET <= 2.0 were misleading, stating that `DateTime.Add()` "Adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance." despite behaving exactly the same way.

Comment: VS tells you "unnecessary assignment" when done this way. Obviously it is very necessary, someone should tell Microsoft.

Comment: @Lucas925 are you using the variable?

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime.AddDays` returns new DateTime that adds specified number of days. You need to assign it to your variable:

```
aux2 = aux2.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

## You are working with immutable functions.

The DateTime function is immutable, once you set variable equal to it, it cannot change, you can though set new variables equal to a working of the function. The AddDay function takes the variable you put into it, but it does not change the original variable, that remains immutable. So you need to set a new variable equall to the original variable + a day.

So all you really need to do is change

`aux2.AddDays(1);`

to

`aux2 = aux2.Adddays(1);`

and then the rest of your comparison functions should work

Comment: This behaviour is not associated with the immutability of the function. The immutability of the type or, in this case, the structure is what matters.