# Index out of bound

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am programming in C# i need to put some things in a string 'xml'

I have the following code

```
        TextBox[] myTextBoxes = new TextBox[] { this.textBox2, this.textBox3, this.textBox4, this.textBox5, this.textBox6, this.textBox7, this.textBox8, this.textBox9, this.textBox10, this.textBox11 };
        TextBox[] ValueBoxes = new TextBox[] { this.textBox3, this.textBox5, this.textBox7, this.textBox9, this.textBox11 };
        CheckBox[] myCheckBoxes = new CheckBox[] { this.checkBox2, this.checkBox4, this.checkBox6, this.checkBox8, this.checkBox10 };
        CheckBox[] myMandBoxes = new CheckBox[] { this.checkBox3, this.checkBox5, this.checkBox7, this.checkBox9, this.checkBox11 };
```

and to verify certain condition i have

```
 xml += "<fields>";

        for (int i = 0; i < myTextBoxes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myTextBoxes[i].Text))
            {
                if (myCheckBoxes[i].Checked == true)
                    xml += "<field display='yes'> ";
                else
                    xml += "<field display='no'> ";
                if (myMandBoxes[i].Checked == true)
                    xml += "<mandatory='yes'>";
                else
                    xml += "<Mandatory='no'>";
                xml += "<label>" + (string)myTextBoxes[i].Text + "</label>";

            }
        }
```

It gives me an Indexoutof boud exception at if (myCheckBoxes[i].Checked == true)

How can i resolve this

Comment: you have way more textboxes in `myTextBoxes` than checkboxes in `myCheckBoxes`

Comment: You said you are 'programming in c++', but you add snippet and tag as [C#].

Comment: You design seems weird to me. Can you explain your requirement? I suspect a proper use of DataBinding will be far more readable, and maintenable. And why not using XmlWriter or any Xml class in the .NEt framework? This will be far more robust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have same number of checkboxes as Textboxes so you can't access them against the same index. 
Your index is starting from `0` to `myTextBoxes.Length`, if `i` is going to be greater than `4`, then you will get this exception.

Not really sure what you are trying to do but you can add a check against the length before accessing the element from myCheckBoxes.

```
if (i < myCheckBoxes.Length && myCheckBoxes[i].Checked == true)
        xml += "<field display='yes'> ";
```

Comment: i know the reason but unable to resolve this programmatically that is through code

Answer (score 2):

Your arrays have different amounts of elements in them so you cannot access them all by using the same index. They will have to be done independently.

Comment: can you please cite as to how

Comment: myMandBoxes and myCheckBoxes both have the same number of items in them, 5 each, but myTextBoxes has many more. in your for loop, you are using the number of items from myTextBoxes and since it has more, once the number of iterations has exceed 5, there are no more items in myCheckBoxes and therefore you get the out of bounds exception. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Use Foreach instead

Here edit as *myTextBoxes.Length - 1*

```
for (int i = 0; i < myTextBoxes.Length - 1; i++)
```

**EDIT:**

Also your checkBox count and Textox count **does not tally**

Comment: are you sure 10th element exist in checkbox list?

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is running to `myTextBoxes.length`, but you are iterating through `myCheckBoxes`. It seems you have more `textboxes` than `CheckBoxes`

Change it to:

for (int i = 0; i < myCheckBoxes.Length; i++)
        {

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < myTextBoxes.Length; i++)
```

use

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCheckBoxes.Length; i++) // or myMandBoxes.Length (Both the CheckBoxes have same items)
```

Because you are looping with CheckBoxes so why having a length of TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Your text box has 11 elements, while checkbox has 5 elements.

Change following

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myTextBoxes[i].Text))
```

to

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myTextBoxes[i].Text) && i < myCheckBoxes.Length )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never use += on strings when constructing them with loops, they are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable), and using it this way, it's just a waste of speed and memory. Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instance instead.

As for your question, the length of the `myTextBoxes` array is 10, so you have items at indexes 0 through 9. The code in this line

```
if (myCheckBoxes[i].Checked == true)
```

tries to access the corresponding item in the `myCheckBoxes` array that has 5 elements (indexed 0 to 4). When `i` becomes 5, the code accesses the `myCheckBoxes[5]` that does not exist, hence the exception.

Other than that, `textBox2` or `checkBox7` are simply awful names for controls, and there are better options in the .net Framework for XML serialization and generation.

Comment: StringBuilder benefits appears only when the number of concatenated string reach a certain threshold (don't remember which). When it's very low, simple concatenation is acceptable (if it's assumed!)

Comment: regarding string vs string builder, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6771/String-Vs-StringBuilder-C. StringBuilder is not good to use in all cases.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to specify that += should not be used in this case (the question very much qualifies for StringBuilder usage :) Will edit.