# Generating random strings by the number in the text box (Visual Basic)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have come here asking for help on how to make my string generator generate the amount of strings typed in TextBox2. For example, if I typed 10 in the box it would generate 10 strings in the RichTextBox1 and if I typed 1 it would generate 1 etc. Here is my code.

```
 Public Function RandomString(ByVal length As Integer) As String
    Dim strb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim chars() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"} 

    Dim UpperBound As Integer = UBound(chars)

    For x As Integer = 1 To length
        strb.Append(chars(Int(Rnd() * UpperBound)))
    Next

    Return strb.ToString

End Function

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Try
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Link Removed...")
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rndstring As String
    rndstring = RandomString(24)
    RichTextBox1.Text = rndstring
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is modify your click handler for Button1 to repeat the number of times specified in `TextBox2`. However, you should verify that the user specified a valid numeric value in the text box as well. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim repeatCnt As Integer

    'Check for valid numeric entry
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, repeatCnt) Then
        For repeatIdx As Integer = 1 To repeatCnt
            Dim rndstring As String
            'Generate random string...
            rndstring = RandomString(24)
            '...and append to text box with a line break
            TextBox1.Text &= rndstring & vbCrLf
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer number in the text box")
    End If
End Sub
```

An extra suggestion might be to change the text box that the user specifies the repeat value to a NumericUpDown control.

Also note that, for large repeat values, the append to the text box `Text` property would not be efficient due to string [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable) so perhaps another `StringBuilder` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method (basically it's just an additional `For`-loop):

```
Private Shared rnd As New Random()
Private Shared chars() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}

Public Shared Function RandomStrings(ByVal length As Int32, count As Int32) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim builder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim strings = New List(Of String)
    For c As Int32 = 1 To count
        For l As Int32 = 1 To length
            builder.Append(chars(rnd.Next(0, chars.Length)))
        Next
        strings.Add(builder.ToString())
        builder.Clear()
    Next
    Return strings
End Function
```

create 100 random strings with length 10:

```
Dim allStrings = RandomStrings(10, 100)
```