# Extension error assignment, how to fix?

Tags: c#, .net

We suppose that for example i have a string, and i want to escape it, and to be well reading)

need a working extension what will solve this problem

i tried.

```
var t = "'";
t.Escape();// == "%27" (what i need), but it not assign result to var. t
t = t.Escape();//works, but ugly.
```

and the extension

```
public static string Escape(this string string_2)
    {
        if (string_2.HasValue())
            string_2 = Uri.EscapeDataString(string_2);
        return string_2;
    }
```

how to fix this extension be working?

Comment: Strings are immutable in .NET. You need to assign new value to variable anyway.

Comment: Strings are immutable, and you can't use `ref` with extension methods, so - you can't do it.

Comment: Also, given that strings *are* immutable, a `t.Escape()` method that somehow did modify `t` would be the ugly syntax, since no other string method works that way!

Comment: Or, you could use 't' as a StringBuilder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`t = t.Escape();` is the usual idiom in .NET for changing a string. E.g. `t = t.Replace("a", "b");` I'd recommend you use this. This is necessary because [strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable).

There are ways around it, but they are uglier IMO. For example, you could use a `ref` parameter (but not on an extension method):

```
public static string Escape (ref string string_2) { ... }
Util.Escape(ref t);
```

Or you could make your own String-like class that's mutable:

```
public class MutableString { /** include implicit conversions to/from string */ }
public static string Escape (this MutableString string_2) { ... }

MutableString t = "'";
t.Escape();
```

I'd caution you that if you use anything besides `t = t.Escape();`, and thus deviate from normal usage, you are likely to confuse anyone that reads the code in the future.

Comment: with another class "helper" i thought), anyway, will remain "ugly" variant :). thx.

Answer (score 1):

"Mutable string" in C# is spelled `StringBuilder`.

So you *could* do something like this:

```
public static void Escape(this StringBuilder text)
{
    var s = text.ToString();
    text.Clear();
    text.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(s));
}
```

But using it wouldn't really be that great:

```
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("'");
test.Escape();
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

The real answer is to use the "ugly" string reassignment

```
t = t.Escape();//works, but ugly.
```

You'll get used to it. :)

Comment: [Offtopic] is your avatar image related to Douglas Adams ? :)

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu Haha yes it is - well spotted. :)