# How to update lines in a CSV file?

Tags: c#, string, csv, filestream

I'm trying to update some part of a string in a file.
Currently my code is:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);

string[] line = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

string eventName = ','+eventNameUpdateTextBox.Text.ToString()+',';
foreach (var l in line)
{
    if (l.Contains(eventName))
    {
        int start = l.IndexOf(eventName);
        l.Remove(start, eventName.Length);
        l.Insert(start, newNameTextBox.Text.ToString());
        lines.Add(l);
    }
    else
    {
        lines.Add(l);
    }   
}

string toCsvOutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray());
```

But the result I'm getting is the same file as before.
When I try to debug it, I see that function:

```
  l.Insert(start, newNameTextBox.Text.ToString());
```

Does not change string and returns the same string as at the beginning. Why does this happen? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the changes to a new (string) variable. This string variable cannot be `l` because is the one being iterated in the `foreach loop` and thus cannot be changed. You have to rely on a temporary variable, as shown in the code below.

```
foreach (var l in line)
{
    if (l.Contains(eventName))
    {
        string temp = l;
        int start = l.IndexOf(eventName);
        temp = temp.Remove(start, eventName.Length);
        temp = temp.Insert(start, newNameTextBox.Text.ToString());
        lines.Add(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        lines.Add(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: now it's changing, but also think i something missed in this code - now it's return string with old value+ new value

Comment: @krill your code seems to be fine but you can replace the third line inside your condition with temp.Replace(eventName, "").

Comment: try `temp = l.Replace(eventName, newNameTextBox.Text.ToString());` - now it's work correct

Comment: @Kirill this too. My previous suggestion was to delete the old string. But if a replacement accounts for both deletion and inclusion, just do it.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, that means they cannot change. You need to create a new string and assign this to the variable.

```
l = l.Remove(start, eventName.Length);
l = l.Insert(start, newNameTextBox.Text.ToString());
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx):

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
> changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
> appear as if you can do this.

[Why .NET String is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

Answer (score 1):

function on strings return the result strings, but do not change the value of the string(most of them if not all)

try this:

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);

    string[] line = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    string eventName = ','+eventNameUpdateTextBox.Text.ToString()+',';
    foreach (var l in line)
    {
        if (l.Contains(eventName))
        {
            int start = l.IndexOf(eventName);
            l = l.Remove(start, eventName.Length);
            l = l.Insert(start, newNameTextBox.Text.ToString());
            lines.Add(l);
        }
        else
        {
            lines.Add(l);
        }   
    }
    string toCsvOutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray());
```