# Quick watch shows that object equal to empty string is not empty string

Tags: c#

Why the quick watch shows the statement p == "" as false, but we are going in the if statement.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string q = "";

        A(q);
    }

    static void A (object p)
    {
        if(p == null || p =="")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Debugger shows false");
        }
    }
```

Is it a bug ?

Note that according to [Compare string and object in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278322/compare-string-and-object-in-c-sharp) `p == ""` should still evaluate to `true` as `""` is an interned string - which indeed happens when code is executed, but fails in quick watch.

[image]

Comment: Look at the green squiggle in the ide. That warning is there for a reason. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `p` is declared as an `object` it is using *reference equality*, not *value equality*.  The problem is that the compiler will "intern" string literals to save memory, so when you do

```
string q = ""
```

the compiler uses a reference to an interned string in memory. Later when you do

```
if(p == "")
```

The compiler has already interned the string, and uses the same reference,so *reference equality* returns true here as well.

The interned string reference is not being used by the QuickWatch window, so the reference `p` and the string `""` are *different* references, and the statement evaluates to `false`.

The *proper* was to compare string values is to use `Equals` which is overridden and will always use value equality:

```
if(p == null || p.Equals(""))  // should evaluate to "true" in both places.
```

or just

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
```

The compiler is warning you of this common mistake; if you hover over the green underline in the IDE you will see the warning message.

Comment: Agreed, it has to be a bug in the Quick Watch tool

Comment: @chomba No, the _proper_ way to compare strings is to use `Equals`.  It's a bug in the program that luckily returns the expected result.

Comment: I see, so it's a limitation of the QuickWatch tool in a sense that it can't be aware of the memory optimization the runtime will perform right?

Comment: Here is a great article by Eric Lippert of the C# team on this subject https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/

Comment: @chomba No, it's highlighting the problem that you are comparing strings by reference equality.  You should never _rely_ on string interning since it's a runtime optimization and in not a guarantee.  Use value comparison methods instead and you'll get proper behavior in all places.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the string class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

object and string are both reference types, but string treats equality operators differently as mentioned in the link.

Also, I use string.IsNullOrEmpty(string) to check if a string is null or empty.

Comment: p == " " is false. You're comparing the reference of p to the reference of an empty string.

Comment: You're comparing an empty string against an object, not another string. You need to cast the object to a string, so it'll do a string comparison and not a reference comparison. It's explained in the link I pasted.

Comment: You are right; the problem is that the string is _interned_, so in the compiled program they are the same reference, but not in the QuickWatch window.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use

```
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ToString()))
```

Comment: i think p is object . And you convert to string p.ToString(); you're comparing object with string is "" .You can't compare object with string