# C# How to comparing two string?

Tags: c#

I want to comparison two string. First is from the dateTimePicker, and second is from file.

```
string firtsdate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");  
string seconddate = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

string FilePath = path;

string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
string[] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int count = 0;

for (int n = 0; n < integerStrings.Length;)            
{
    count = integerStrings[n].Length;               
    //Console.Write(count + "\n");
    count--;                                         
    if (count > 2)                                  
    {
        string datastart;
        string dataend;

        if (integerStrings[n] == firtsdate)
        {
            datastart = integerStrings[n];
            Console.Write(datastart);
            dataend = (DateTime.Parse(datastart).AddDays(1)).ToShortDateString();
            Console.Write(dataend + "\n");
        }
        else
        {
            n = n + 7;
        }
    }
}
```

File looks like this:

- 2016-07-01
- 2016-07-02
- 2016-07-06
- ...

Problem is that they do not want to compare two of the same value, like 2016-07-02 == 2016-07-02 (from file).

Comment: convert two strings to datetime variables and compare like this... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you inspect the values you are trying to compare?  Maybe they aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare string and object in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278322/compare-string-and-object-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
string[] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

A line break on Windows is `"\r\n"` - so each line in your split will end in a `\r`. The simplest way to fix this is to just replace those two lines with:

```
string[] integerStrings = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about your date time format, and strings are correct, you can compare 2 strings by `Equals`, or `Compare`.
The end of line character in linux is `\n` (line feed) and windows is `\r` (carriage return), and `\r\n` for both, so you should split line by these characters or read file line by line.