# Clear all interning strings in Linqpad?

Tags: c#, .net, linqpad

How can I clear all interned strings in linqpad?

Looking at this example :

```
//var asd="asd";
string s = new string(new  []{'a','s','d'});
Console.WriteLine (string.IsInterned(s));
```

It always return `null`  , which is fine.

But once I un-remark the first line it always yield `"asd"` even if I remark it again.

It seems that the only solution is to close the program and start it again.

*p.s. : in visual studio it's always returns the desired results (console mode).*

Comment: this SO thread might offer some reason why you are having problems clearing it: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable

In order for you to get the desired results in a console app, don't you have to uncomment that line and rebuild? which is the same as unloading and reloading LINQPad..no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>LINQPad maintains the AppDomain between runs, so everything that's static will remain in memory. You can change this behavior by going to **Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Always use fresh application domains**.</strike>

While the above is true, it seems string interning is performed at a *process* level (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/22/51371.aspx)). So there's no way to reset that besides restarting.

Comment: "Cancel all threads and reset" (Shift+Ctrl+F5) is another way to clear the AppDomain. But as Eli says, interning happens at a process level, so it won't have any effect in this case.