# String Replace For Insert

Tags: c#, sql

I have an application that reads from a file and inserts the contents of the file into a table. I split the data up into substrings respective of their fields. For one of the fields, I need to replace a character (`F`) with a `0`. I have tried this, however it isn't working (`F` is still being inserted).

```
string[] mylines02 =   System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\BillingExport\\IMPORTS\\ACNTBILL.ALL.TYPE02.FRMATED.txt");

List<ACCOUNT_BILL_PLANS> table2_1Input = new List<ACCOUNT_BILL_PLANS>();
ACCOUNT_BILL_PLANS table2_1 = new ACCOUNT_BILL_PLANS();

for (int i = 0; i < mylines02.Length; i++)
{
    var fixf_over = mylines02[i].Substring(64, 3).Trim().ToString();
    if (fixf_over.Contains("F"))
    {
        fixf_over.Replace("F", "0"); 
    }

    table2_1Input.Add(table2_1);

    using (SqlCommand cmd72 = new SqlCommand(insertString72, _cond2))
    {
        cmd72.Parameters.Add("@OVERPAYMENT_LIMIT", SqlDbType.NChar);

        cmd72.Parameters["@OVERPAYMENT_LIMIT"].Value = fixf_over;

        cmd72.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _cond2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `fixf_over.Replace("F", "0");` will not modify the original string it will return a new string so assign it back like `fix_over  = fixf_over.Replace("F", "0");`

Comment: Also see [Why .NET String is immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2365272/961113)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply it to the variable?

```
fixf_over = fixf_over.Replace("F", "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Replace` does no inplace update, but instead returns a string that has those replacements you are looking for:

```
fixf_over = fixf_over.Replace("F", "0");
```