# string does not act like reference type

Tags: c#

In the code below, changes on `cpy` value does not affect `ori` value, so string does not behave like a reference type :

```
string ori = "text 1";
string cpy = ori;
cpy = "text 2";
Console.WriteLine("{0}", ori);
```

but, a class has a different behaviour :

```
class WebPage
{
    public string Text;
}

// Now look at reference type behaviour
WebPage originalWebPage = new WebPage();
originalWebPage.Text = "Original web text";

// Copy just the URL
WebPage copyOfWebPage = originalWebPage;

// Change the page via the new copy of the URL
copyOfWebPage.Text = "Changed web text";

// Write out the contents of the page
// Output=Changed web text
Console.WriteLine ("originalWebPage={0}",
                           originalWebPage.Text);
```

can someone tell me why the behaviour is different between a class and string while the two of them are reference types ?

Comment: Strings are immutable and can't be changed

Comment: the best thing i can say is to lookup how reference types work.

Comment: Actually, no, a class does *not* have a different behaviour. You are just doing two different things in your example: For strings, you assign a new value (`"text 2"`) to the `string` variable `cpy` itself. For your class `WebPage`, you just assign a new value (`"Changed web text"`) to a *property* (`Text`) of (the instance referenced by) your variable `copyOfWebPage`.

Comment: In this line `cpy = "text 2";` you are changing the string that variable `cpy` references.  In this line `copyOfWebPage.Text = "Changed web text";` you are not changing the object that `copyOfWebPage` references, you are changing the property `Text`, of the object referenced by both variables.

Comment: more info on string immutability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable

Comment: @DLeh Irrelevant to the question though. What this question has to do with immutability ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel strings "not acting like reference types" is a consequence of them being immutable.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: nothing, but all fall into the same trap.

Comment: @DLeh Forget about string. Even if you use `StringBuilder` you'll see the same output. because OP is modifying the reference with new instance, not mutating it(which is not possible with string).

Comment: no need to downvote ! the first answer is fine. i didnt know that behaviour. It is different than the c++ that I know more.

Comment: @HichamfromCppDependTeam C++ acts exactly the same too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no c++ does not act the same. string is not immutable and it is not a reference type. the = operator is used to copy the content of the string litteral to the string. (in : string str = "abc").So there is no reference behaviour in cpy  = ori. the content of ori is simply copied to cpy. cpy is not a reference to the same data in c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though `strings` are immutable this situation has nothing to do with that. When you assign a new reference to a reference type, you are throwing away the old one. In your second example, you are changing a property of your object, since they are pointing to same location, both of them are affected.

But when you do

```
cpy = "text 2";
```

It means create a new string and store it's reference into `cpy` and throw away the old reference of `cpy`.

Answer (score 2):

Classes behave exactly like strings, you are just not doing the same thing in your two examples.

```
WebPage originalWebPage = new WebPage();
originalWebPage.Text = "Original web text";    

WebPage copyOfWebPage = originalWebPage;

//Overwrite the copy variable just like you did before
copyOfWebPage = new WebPage();
copyOfWebPage.Text = "Modified web text";

Console.WriteLine ("originalWebPage={0}", originalWebPage.Text);
Console.WriteLine ("copyOfWebPage={0}", copyOfWebPage.Text);
```

[<kbd>Run this example</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0tda3n)

The classes example makes it more obvious what is going on, when you did

```
string cpy = ori;
cpy = "text 2";
```

you copied the text of `ori` in to `cpy`, you then immedatly threw away that value an copied `"text 2"` in to `cpy`, you never actually "modified" the value of the object `cpy` refers to, you just made it point to a new object.