# How Instances of immutable types are inherently thread-safe

Tags: c#, thread-safety, immutability

I search about Why .NET String is immutable? And got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428743/1968030) answer:

> Instances of immutable types are inherently thread-safe, since no
> thread can modify it, the risk of a thread modifying it in a way that
> interfers with another is removed (the reference itself is a different
> matter).

So I want to know How Instances of immutable types are inherently thread-safe?

Comment: Isn't the text snipped you included already answering the question?

Comment: At the very least, if you don't understand it, point out which part you don't understand. A valid answer to your question could simply copy and paste the quote in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why Instances of immutable types are inherently thread-safe?

Because an instance of a `string` type can't be mutated across multiple threads. This effectively means that one thread changing the `string` won't result in that same `string` being changed in another thread, since a new `string` is allocated in the place the mutation is taking place.

Generally, everything becomes easier when you create an object once, and then only observe it. Once you need to modify it, a new local copy gets created.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object):

> Immutable objects can be useful in multi-threaded applications.
>   Multiple threads can act on data represented by immutable objects
>   without concern of the data being changed by other threads. Immutable
>   objects are therefore **considered to be more thread-safe** than mutable
>   objects.

@xanatos (and wikipedia) point out that immutable isn't always thread-safe. We like to make that correlation because we say "any type which has persistent non-changing state is safe across thread boundaries", but may not be always the case. Assume a type is immutable from the "outside", but internally will need to modify it's state in a way which may not be safe when done in parallel from multiple threads, and may cause undetermined behavior. This means that although immutable, it is not thread safe.

To conclude, immutable != thread-safe. But immutability does take you one step closer, when done right, towards being able to do multi-threaded work correctly.

Comment: While for *string* it is surely correct, an immutable type could only appear from the "observer" POV being immutable (the immutable collections of Microsoft use various tricks to share memory between themselves). I am not sure that "immutable" strongly implies "thread safe" in general.

Comment: @xanatos There's a difference between immutable and read only. An object can have a read only interface but still be mutable. Saying it is immutable is a stronger guarantee.

Comment: It is hard to synchronize threads accesses to resources (objects or others OS things). Why it is hard to synchronize these accesses? Because it is hard to guarantee that there won’t be race conditions between the multiple write accesses and read accesses done by multiple threads on multiple objects. What if there are no more write accesses? In other words, what if the state of the objects threads are accessing, doesn’t change? There is no more need for synchronization!

Comment: @BogdanBanciu You're right. That's what I try to explain in the first part. Once you eliminate mutation and only "observe" the value of the object, life becomes easier.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:**

Because you only write the data in 1 thread and always read it *after* writing in multiple threads. Because there is no read/write conflict possible, it's thread safe.

**The long answer:**

A string is essentially a pointer to a buffer of memory. Basically what happens is that you create a buffer, fill it with characters and then expose the pointer to the outside world.

Note that you cannot access the contents of the string before the string object itself is constructed, which enforces this ordering of 'write data', then 'expose pointer'. If you would do it the other way around (I guess that's theoretically possible), problems might arrise.

If another thread (let's say: CPU) reads the pointer, it is a 'new pointer' for the CPU, which therefore requires the CPU to go to the 'real' memory and then read the data. If it would take the pointer contents from cache, we would have had a problem.

The last piece of the puzzle has to do with memory management: we have to know it's a 'new' pointer. In .NET we know this is the case: memory on the heap is basically never re-used until a GC occurs. The garbage collector then does a mark, sweep and compact.

Now, you might argue that the 'compact' phase reuses pointers, therefore changing the contents of the pointers. While this is true, the GC also has to stop the threads and force a full memory fence, which in simple terms, flushes the CPU cache. After that, all memory access is guaranteed, which ensures you always have to go to memory after the GC phase completes.

As you can see there is no way to read the data by not reading it directly from memory (the way it was written). Since it's immutable, the contents remain the same for all threads until it's eventually collected. As such, it's thread safe.

---

I've seen some discussion about immutable here, that suggests you can change an internal state. Of course, the moment you start changing things, you can potentially introduce read/write conflicts.

The definition of that I'm using here is to keep the contents **constant** after creation. That is: write once, read many, don't change (any) state after exposing the pointer. You get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest problem in multi-threading code is two threads *accessing* the same memory cell at the same time with at least one of them *modifying* this memory cell.

If none of the threads can *modify* a memory cell, the problem does not exist any longer.

Because an immutable variable is not modifyable, it can be used from several threads without any further measures (for example locks).