# How do I add text into my string?

Tags: c#, path, visual-studio-2015

I though it was simple. but I didn't manage to make this line of code add "\Game_Progress.xml" to my *String* 
`code_file.Insert(code_file.Length, "\\Game_Progress.xml");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why .NET String is immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the string using the `+=` operator:

```
code_file += "\\Game_Progress.xml";
```

Note: If you want to combine a path, you should consider using the [Path Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(code_file, "\\Game_Progress.xml")
```

Answer (score -1):

C# can require an @prior to the string when using backslashes. Try:

code_file.Insert(code_file.Length, @"\\Game_Progress.xml");

Comment: `\\` is escaped in the question...

Comment: Oh I've never seen that method, always just used @. Well, you learn something new.