# How to add CheckBoxList item on StringBuilder Use to Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, stringbuilder

How can I add CheckBoxList Item on String Builder.

```
CheckBoxList cblItem = new CheckBoxList();
cblItem.ID = "cblItem";

var MainCatGroup = subCatDet.GroupBy(q => q.catCode).Select(q => new { CatName = q.Key, Items = q.ToArray() }).Select(q => new { CatName = q.CatName, Items = q.Items.OrderBy(t => t.catCode).ToArray() }).ToArray();
foreach (var mainCat in MainCatGroup)
{
    sb.Append(string.Format("<li><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\">{0}</a>", mainCat.CatName.ToString()));
    sb.Append(string.Format("<ul>"));

    foreach (var item in mainCat.Items)
    {
        string Subcat = item.subCat.ToString();
        string catCode= item.catCode.ToString();
        sb.Append(string.Format("<li>"));
----->  sb.Append(string.Format(cblItem.Items.Add(new ListItem("{0},{1}")), Subcat, catCode));     <----
        sb.Append(string.Format("</li>"))
     }
        litList.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

So, How can i edit below the line?

```
sb.Append(string.Format(cblItem.Items.Add(new ListItem("{0},{1}")), Subcat, catCode));
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @YacoubMassad when i use stringbuilder add dynamically item on the checkboxlist, i have a error on the line. so i dont know its logical problem or another

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Please give more context.

Comment: @ekrem-tapan StringBuilder can't be used to add dynamically items in CheckBoxList. StringBuilder can build a message which you can later add to the list. Are you trying to add the same string to the list and to StringBuilder?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. :) StringBuilder is to avoid multiple string creation (string is an immutable type). [Here you can learn more about StringBuilder purpose.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

Comment: @mikes u have a any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
cblItem.Items.Add(new ListItem(sb.ToString()), Subcat, catCode);
```

Or better:

```
cblItem.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Format("{0},{1}", Subcat, catCode));
```

You also souldn't mix naming convetions. The Subcat and MainCatGroup local variables shouldn't be named starting upper case letter.

And in the and you can also try StringFormat.AppendFormat ([more details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
sb.AppendFormat("2) {0}, {1}", var1, var2);
```