# Tried replace, trim but cannot remove the quotation mark from a string C#

Tags: c#

I am making a application which can convert a excel file to CSV file.

However, some string contain a quotation mark, so when the CSV exported, some of the String was splits to two cell which should be in one cell.

For example:

```
"39.6cm (15.6") HD (1366x768),97cm", "Core2 M3321" //15.6"<===have a quotation mark
```

I tried to use "trim(), replace(), Insert()" to remove the quotation, but it doesn't work. I don't know way.

```
 if (HTMLTable.Contains("\""))
 {

    HTMLTable.Trim(new Char[] {'"'}); //Try to remove quotation
    HTMLTable.Replace("\"", ""); 
    HTMLTable.Insert(HTMLTable.IndexOf('"') - 1, "\\");
 }

 csvRecord += "\",\"" + HTMLTable + "\",0"; //Append the String into the CSV builder
```

I tried a lot of solutions, but it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you assing the result of the string operations? Strings are immutable, which means `.Trim()` and `.Replace()` return *new* strings. A simple `myString.Replace("\"", "")` is enough.

Comment: I would assume ( because it's TV product ) that it's not a quotation `"` mark but indication of inches `''` [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't assigning the result of the Trim or replace to a string.

You need to do something like

```
HtmlTable = HtmlTable.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Looking at your comment, if you don't like string.Empty then you need to do

```
HtmlTable = HtmlTable.Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: `String.Empty` and `""` are identical.

Comment: Yes. I just think string.Empty is neater.

Comment: @Stuart I agree with you. (And btw, Panagiotis  is not the OP)

Comment: Forgot to assign the result... Thx a lot. LOL

Answer (score 2):

Since [strings are immutable in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2365272/993547), you can't change their values. That means that a new string is made on every write operation on a string.

Because of that, every method which 'modifies' a string returns a new string instead. So you have to assign that value:

```
HTMLTable = HTMLTable.Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know, that .Replace doesn't change existing string but return new string after replace operation.

```
HTMLTable = HTMLTable.Replace("\"", "");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx