# Removing the 3rd and 4th character using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete the 3rd and 4th character from a string from a value from a database which has a serialized data, for below example i need to remove the number 2 and 3, i am using below code to remove the first character from a string, since the replace method needs to find a specific character then replace it with, but below string is unique, i think the method that i am looking for is remove.

```
00230A01E0
```

Removing the first character

```
String data = '00230A01E0';
data.Remove(0,1);
```

So the final output will look like this

```
000A01E0
```

Comment: This question is just a duplicate of all the other "I can't get the string-mutating methods to work" questions that already exist on Stack Overflow. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43387831)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so such functions will always return a *new* string.

Try

```
data = data.Remove(2, 2);
```

i.e. go to index 2 (character 3) and remove 2 characters.

**In future, I highly recommend checking the functions on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) before posting here, since the documentation clearly states that a *new string* is returned.**

Comment: @ john i am tried but i cannot get to achieve my desire output `000A01E0`

Comment: @KaoriYui It [works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s5ZkaG)

Comment: @ john Got it working, thanks!