# Replace text in string and save to file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, text, replace

I want remove a text if the program finds the text to replace, so I prepared this code:

```
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"pathtofile");
        int Object = 0;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {

            if (line.Contains("Object"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("contain!");
                dsObject++;
            }

            if (Object == 1)
            {
                line.Replace("Object", " ");
                MessageBox.Show(line);
            }


            File.AppendAllText(@"savefile.txt", line + Environment.NewLine);
            string result = line;
           // MessageBox.Show(line);


        }
```

This does not work.

Comment: Why you have two different counters? You never increment `Object`

Comment: _What_ you want to remove and what doesn't work?

Comment: I want remove word "Object" in my file, but I have a few such expressions so I want to remove it from a given line with a given repetition of this word.

Comment: @MarekPucek does your accepted answer really work because I am getting a compalation error in `line = line.Replace("Object",String.Empty);` because `line` is a foreach iteration variable

Comment: Use `for` instead `foreach` if you want to alter the content of the collection/array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable) in c#

therefore have to replace

```
  line.Replace("Object", " ");
```

with

```
line = line.Replace("Object", String.Empty);
```

Edit

as s[laven-hvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7308680/slaven-hvar) said you cannot change `foreach` item
therefore you to do change to "normal" `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
     lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("Object", String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: `line = line.Replace("Object",String.Empty);` won't compile because `line` is a foreach iteration variable

Comment: This answer is partial, line could not be altered because of the `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop instead of a foreach loop because `line = line.Replace("Object", String.Empty)` will not compile because `line` is a foreach iteration variable. Instead of `line = line.Replace("Object", String.Empty)` use `lines[i]=lines[i].Replace("Object", String.Empty);` in a for loop:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"pathtofile");
int Object = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].Contains("Object"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("contain!");
        dsObject++;
    }

    if (Object == 1)
    {
        lines[i]=lines[i].Replace("Object", String.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show(lines[i]);
    }

    File.AppendAllText(@"savefile.txt", lines[i] + Environment.NewLine);
    string result = lines[i];
}
```

If you want your code to be shorter you can use this LINQ solution:

```
var result = lines.Select(x => x.Replace("Object", String.Empty)).ToList();
result.ForEach(line=>File.AppendAllText(@"savefile.txt", line + Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: The linq proposal would scan the data twice, for large data would not be a good advice, but could be modified fo use linq and do just one (doing the replacement inside the `.Foreach`).