# Immutable Strings

Tags: c#, string, heap-memory, stack-memory

Now, to me, strings have always been value types. Learning that they're not, and are in fact what's called Immutable String is very interesting, but holds a very important question:

When would a string not be an immutable string?

See, when I declare a string like this:

```
string testString = "abc";
```

The stack should now hold the variable declaration and the heap the value, to which the variable is referencing.
If I declared a second string:

```
string secondString = testString;
```

Both variables should now reference the same position on the heap.
If I did this:

```
secondString = testString + "def";
```

The value on the heap should be copied, modified and a second value should lie on the heap.

I understand this is what an immutable string is.

But since this is pretty much how I've always been declaring and working with strings, I wonder if there is another way, a mutable string, so to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, strings are immutable and that's that.

```
var string1 = "string";
var string2 = string1;
string2 = "string2";

Console.WriteLine(string1);
Console.WriteLine(string2);
```

**Output**

```
string
string2
```

Secondly, why do you really want an mutable string? Here are many reasons why strings "are" immutable. see  [Why .NET String is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

Lastly, if you really want an immutable string you can create an instance of `StringBuilder`  You get mutability, however it will reallocate its internal buffer every-time it needs to, or you can roll your own fancy pants class.