# C# method with parameters

Tags: c#, methods

I've written some code to check whether a given subject name exists in my SQL database. Please see below:

```
string exists = String.Empty;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Subject_Name FROM Subject WHERE Subject_Name ='" + input + "'", connection))
   {
     using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; j++)
                 {
                       exists = reader.GetValue(j) + "";
                 }
            }
      }
   }
}
```

note: connectionString has already been declared above in my program

I am using this code in a few methods and don't want to have duplicated code, therefore I am thinking of making this into a method.

Problem lies in that the next piece of code in my methods in which i use the above code uses the `exists` string and checks whether or not it is empty.

Pseudo code below:

```
if(String.ISNullOrEmpty(exists))
{
//do some code
}
else
{
//do some code
}
```

I have made the method as follows:

```
private static string SubjectExistsChecker(string input, string exists)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Subject_Name FROM Subject WHERE Subject_Name ='" + input + "'", connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; j++)
                            {
                                exists = reader.GetValue(j) + "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return exists;
            }
        }
```

I then call the method as follows:

```
MethodName()
{
//some code asking for subjectName which we call `input`

 String exists = string.Empty;
 SubjectExistsChecker(input, exists);


 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(exists))
{
//do some code
}
else
{
//do some code
}
```

When writing the code out fully (not using method) as shown at the top, this works.

Now that I've made the method, it doesn't work and `exists` stays null.

Can anyone help? Where am I going wrong? I'm guessing its something to do with the `exists` string.

Comment: Because you never assign the result your method returns to any variable. Do `exists = SubjectExistsChecker(input, exists);` and (optionally) remove the `string exists` parameter and declare the variable locally. Or make the method of type `void`, remove the return and add a `ref` before the `string exists` parameter, to modify the variable you passed as `exists` to the method.

Comment: `string exists = SubjectExistsChecker(input, exists);`

Comment: Aside: use Dapper instead. There's no good reason to mess around with `SqlDataReader` yourself, especially not if you're going to use it in this way. This will also take care of parameterization, another issue that you currently have. And last but not least: use `IF EXISTS` or `SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` in your *query*, don't make the C# code do all the heavy lifting -- that's what your database is for.

Comment: @BoredomOverload yes that works now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting your return value:

Add this:

```
exists = SubjectExistsChecker(input, exists);
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it is a bad practice to directly concatenate SQL strings due to SQL Injection security issues.

You could and should use a parameterized query, and set the value in the parameters.

Example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2

Secondly. You are not assigning the string to your `exists` variable outside of the scope of the `SubjectExistsChecker` method. Strings are immutable.

This should work for your case:

```
 String exists = string.Empty;
 exists = SubjectExistsChecker(input, exists);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using [`String` and they are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable) in their nature though they are reference types.

You will need to return the string and assign back to your variable:

```
String exists = string.Empty;
exists = SubjectExistsChecker(input, exists);
```

and looks like it will be a single record, if yes you don't need to do a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using the value that you compute in your `SubjectExistsChecker()`.
In order to use what you `return` from within a method, you could perform an assignment upon the call to the method, like so:

```
String exists = SubjectExistsChecker(input, exists);
```

But if we go this way, we don't really need to supply it as a parameter to the method - because if you look at it, nothing depends on this parameter.
Also note that we tend to name methods with verbs - as it reflects their nature. For example, your method could be named `DoesSubjectExist`.
So you could adjust the method like so:

```
private static string DoesSubjectExist(string input)
{
    string exists = "";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Subject_Name FROM Subject WHERE Subject_Name ='" + input + "'", connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; j++)
                    {
                        exists = reader.GetValue(j) + "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return exists;
    }
}
```

But still it is unclear what did you want the result of this method to be? 
What we can guess from the name, we want to check if a subject exists - we don't have to know what it is. 
In that case, it would make sense that the method returns either `true` if subject with given name exists or `false` otherwise.
So, with further adjustments:

```
private static bool DoesSubjectExist(string input)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        // Note that query will probably need to be changed too for a more optimal solution.
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Subject_Name FROM Subject WHERE Subject_Name ='" + input + "'", connection)) 
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Do we need this loop?
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // There is at least one match - so the subject exists.
                    if (reader.FieldCount > 0) return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false; // If we get here, we didn't find anything.
    }
}
```

So this will be much more expressive. Note your use case:

```
MethodName()
{
    //some code asking for subjectName which we call `input`

    if (DoesSubjectExist(input))
    {
        //do some code
    }
    else
    {
        //do some code
    }
}
```

Also, please take the advice other people here are giving and abstract your SQL data access somehow.