# Replace pipe character in string

Tags: powershell

From a SQL query (Postgres DB) the following line output is captured in a string:

```
    id         |                           title                            |     cur_status_time
```

I am trying to replace the pipe character into something else.

```
 $line -replace "|",";"
```

but this is not working.

I tried:

```
$line.replace("|",";")
```

but its not working, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [-replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1#replacement-operator) operator uses regex matching. The `|` is a [special character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in regex. You need to escape it with a backslash `\`:

```
$line = $line -replace "\|", ";"
```

Although this should have worked too:

```
$line = $line.Replace("|", ";")
```

**Note:** Strings in .NET are immutable ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)). Operations like `Replace` don't change the original string, so you have to assign the result back to `$line`.

Comment: Good point, I should have made that clearer. Since I was writing this up for own notes just now, let me offer an improved version.

Comment: It is advisable to use single quotes (`'...'`) with `-replace`, because `"..."` could create confusion with PowerShell's up-front string expansion (interpolation); e.g., `"$1"` would be interpreted as a variable reference.

Comment: If you do use `"..."` because you want to embed PowerShell variable values and expressions in the strings up front, be sure to escape `$` instances that are meant for the _regex engine_ as `\`$`. The alternative is to stick with single quotes and use the `-f` operator to embed a value; e.g. `'foo-{0}' -f $var`. Either way, a pitfall is that any metacharacters embedded in variable values will have syntactic meaning, and to treat them *verbatim* requires a call to `[regex]::Escape()` for the regex operand, and doubling of any embedded `$` characters for the substitution operand.