# String reference in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

As string is ref type in dotnet, when we update **variable x**, there should be update in **y** too ? (as it is referring value of x). sample program given below, how value of y is not changing when x is updated?

```
public void assignment()
{
    string x= "hello";
    string y=x; // referencing x as string is ref type in .net
    x = x.Replace('h','j');
    Console.WriteLine(x); // gives "jello" output
    Console.WriteLine(y); // gives "hello" output 
}
```

Comment: No, basically. There's a difference between changing the value of a variable (which doesn't affect other variables) and changing the content of an object. See https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010236/22656

Comment: You are talking about Mutable vs Immutable. String is Immutable and it always keeps the same value. String is also Reference type and it does not have a default allocation size.

Comment: @Bizhan: It's not really about immutability. Even if strings were mutable, changing the value of one variable wouldn't change the other variable. (For example, suppose we were using `StringBuilder` instead of `string`, and the line in question was `x = null;` - that wouldn't make `y` null.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think it *is* also about immutability, because e.g. `StringBuilder.Replace` mutates and returns itself, so `x = x.Replace(...)` would change the value in `y` also.

Comment: @Charlieface: Which is precisely why I *didn't* use `Replace` in my example. Suppose `string` were actually mutable, but `Replace` had its current behavior of returning a new string instead of modifying the existing one. (Maybe there would be a `ReplaceInExistingObject` method that would mutate it, for example.) The behavior in this question *would not change at all*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right that, initially, both `x` and `y` reference the same object:

```
       +-----------+
y   -> |   hello   |
       +-----------+
            ^
x   --------+
```

Now have a look at this line:

```
x = x.Replace('h','j');
```

The following happens:

1. [`x.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_Char_System_Char_) creates a *new* string (with h replaced by j) and returns a reference to this new string.

   ```
          +-----------+    +------------+
   y   -> |   hello   |    |   jello    |
          +-----------+    +------------+
               ^
   x   --------+
   ```
2. With `x = ...`, you assign `x` to this new reference. `y` still references the old string.

   ```
          +-----------+    +------------+
   y   -> |   hello   |    |   jello    |
          +-----------+    +------------+
                                 ^
   x   --------------------------+
   ```

---

So how *do* you modify a string in-place? You don't. C# does not support modifying strings in-place. Strings are [deliberately designed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2365272/87698) as an *immutable* data structure. For a mutable string-like data structure, use `StringBuilder`:

```
var x = new System.Text.StringBuilder("hello");
var y = x;

// note that we did *not* write x = ..., we modified the value in-place
x.Replace('h','j');

// both print "jello"
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are already good answers here why this happens.
If you however want both to print "jello" you can assign x to y by reference using the `ref` keyword.

```
string x = "hello";
ref string y = ref x;
x = x.Replace('h', 'j');
Console.WriteLine(x); // gives "jello" output
Console.WriteLine(y); // gives "jello" output
```

More info on Ref locals [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals).

Comment: Very good point, although I personally prefer to call it *"make y an alias for x"*, to avoid the ambiguity of the phrase "assigning by reference".

Answer (score 1):

The string returned is a NEW string reference.
In regard of string.Replace() the MSDN says:

> "This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of oldValue are replaced by newValue"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0.

As mentioned by @Heinzi - strings are immutable and most of the actions taken on strings result in new strings:

> "String objects are immutable: they cannot be changed after they have been created. All of the String methods and C# operators that appear to modify a string actually return the results in a new string object"

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#:~:text=String%20objects%20are%20immutable%3A%20they,in%20a%20new%20string%20object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#:%7E:text=String%20objects%20are%20immutable%3A%20they,in%20a%20new%20string%20object).

Cheers!