# Can't remove text from string using button

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to make a super simple program where you use 10 different buttons to write in a code (kind of like the code to the door of an appartment complex). All the buttons have this click event:

```
    private void number_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (sender as Button);

        if (code.Length == 4)
        {
            code.Remove(0, 1);
        }

        switch (button.Name)
        {
            case "button_1":
                code += "1";
                break;

            case "button_2":
                code += "2";
                break;

            case "button_3":
                code += "3";
                break;

            case "button_4":
                code += "4";
                break;

            case "button_5":
                code += "5";
                break;

            case "button_6":
                code += "6";
                break;

            case "button_7":
                code += "7";
                break;

            case "button_8":
                code += "8";
                break;

            case "button_9":
                code += "9";
                break;

            case "button_0":
                code += "0";
                break;
        }

        label1.Text = code;
    }
```

I'm simply trying to make so the number the user presses get added to the code string. When there length of the string reaches 4 it is supposed to remove the first character so that there is never more than 4 characters in the string. For some reason this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `code = code.Remove(0, 1);` - you need to store the return value of from Remove method

Comment: Because [strings in C# are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428743/107625).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is that `string` is *immutable* and so

```
code.Remove(0, 1);
```

computes result string and *throws it away*. You should assign the result string back:

```
...
code = code.Remove(0, 1);
...
```

You can get rid of long `switch case` and obtain `digit` from the button's name:

```
private void number_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var button = (sender as Button);

  // Add new digit to the right
  code += button.Name[button.Name.Length - 1].ToString();

  // Ensure code is at most 5 digits long by removing digits from the left
  code = code.Substring(Math.Clamp(code.Length - 5, 0, code.Length)); 
}
```

Comment: Ah okay I understand. Thank you very much! And using the name of the button to get the number was very clever. I did however not understand that last part with substring, math.clamp etc. Whould you mind explaining further how that workls?

Comment: @MacA: `Math.Clamp(x, min, max)` returns `x` when it within `min..max`, `min` when `x` is too small (x < min) and `max` when `x` is too large (x > max). Here I put `Math.Clamp` to ensure that `Substring` has argument in valid range

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the `code` variable you can use `Substring` method.

```
if (code.Length == 4)
{
    code = code.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Because [strings in C# are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428743/107625).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the fact that `System.String` instances are immutable. This means you can't modify the string `code` points to, but you can make it point to another string. The `Remove` method of `System.String` doesn't actually remove anything, it just creates a new string without the unwanted characters and returns a reference to it. This means that instead of

```
code.Remove(0, 1);
```

You want:

```
code = code.Remove(0, 1);
```