# Are strings in Ruby mutable?

Tags: ruby, string, immutability, mutable

Consider the following code:

```
$ irb
> s = "asd"
> s.object_id   # prints 2171223360
> s[0] = ?z     # s is now "zsd"
> s.object_id   # prints 2171223360 (same as before)
> s += "hello"  # s is now "zsdhello"
> s.object_id   # prints 2171224560 (now it's different)
```

Seems like individual characters can be changed w/o creating a new string. However appending to the string apparently creates a new string.

**Are strings in Ruby mutable?**

Comment: Yes, and answerable via trivial search.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608493/why-did-matz-choose-to-make-strings-mutable-by-default-in-ruby

Comment: @DaveNewton: Isn't it great how easy it is to find dups on SO as you can almost count on an SO topic coming up first on google?

Comment: `+` is Concatenating and will return a new string. `<<` is Appending and will append to the given string object (not create a new one).

Comment: @EdS. Yes and no; yes because it's been answered, no because it means people would rather just ask a question than do even a modest amount of research.

Comment: `s += "hello"` is shorthand for `s = s + "hello"`, which runs the `String#+` method, which always returns a new string.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Well, great for us who close topics and answer questions I suppose.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, strings in Ruby, unlike in Python, are mutable.

`s += "hello"` is **not** appending `"hello"` to `s` - an entirely new string object gets created. To append to a string 'in place', use `<<`, like in:

```
s = "hello"
s << "   world"
s # hello world
```

Comment: Does it make sense to think of `a += b` as `a = a + b` in Ruby? That would make it clear why `s += "hello"` creates a new string.

Comment: @tuple_cat Yes, that's how `+=` is implemented, thus redefining `+` yields a redefined `+=`.

Answer (score 17):

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :026 > s="foo"
 => "foo" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :027 > s.object_id
 => 70120944881780 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :028 > s<<"bar"
 => "foobar" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :029 > s.object_id
 => 70120944881780 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :031 > s+="xxx"
 => "foobarxxx" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :032 > s.object_id
 => 70120961479860
```

so, Strings are mutable, but `+=` operator creates a new String. `<<` keeps old

Answer (score 10):

Appending in [Ruby String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) is not `+=`, it is `<<`

So if you change `+=` to `<<` your question gets addressed by itself

Comment: +1. As explained at http://www.rubyfleebie.com/appending-to-a-string/, "`+=` will create a new String instance and will assign it to your left object. On the other hand, `<<` will append the new string directly into your already existing left object."

Answer (score 9):

Strings in Ruby are mutable, but you can change it with freezing.

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "foo".freeze
=> "foo"
irb(main):002:0> s << "bar"
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby Strings are mutable. But you need to use << for concatenation rather than +.
In fact concatenating string with
 **+ operator(immutable)** because it creates new string object.
 **<< operator(mutable)**  because it changes in the same object.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can make of [this pull request](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/487), it will become possible in Ruby 3.0 to add a "magic comment" that will make all string *immutable*, rather than mutable.

Because it seems you have to explicitly add this comment, it seems like the answer to "are string mutable *by default*?" will still be yes, but a sort of conditional yes - depends on whether you wrote the magic comment into your script or not.

**EDIT**

I was pointed to this [bug/issue on Ruby-Lang.org](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11473) that definitively states that *some* type of strings in Ruby 3.0 will in fact be immutable by default.