# Fundamental question about boxing / c#

Tags: c#, boxing

Is it possible to change the value stored inside `bar` after it has been added?

I have tried 'boxing' the string `foo` but it doesnt work.

```
string foo = "aaaaaaa";
var bar = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div") { InnerHtml =foo };
foo = "zzzzzz";
plcBody.Controls.Add(bar);//want this to contain 'zzzzzz'
```

Comment: Quick comment, as Nick's answer explains it all other than my picky complaint about wording - this has *nothing* to do with boxing. String is a reference type; boxing only comes into play at all when it comes to value types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do that you have to set the value, like this:

```
string foo = "aaaaaaa";
var bar = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div") { InnerHtml = foo };
bar.InnerHtml = "zzzzzz";
plcBody.Controls.Add(bar);
```

[Strings themselves are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net)  (in .NET at least, this isn't universally true), you can't change it after it's been passed...you passed the **value** of the variable, which is a string reference - you haven't passed a reference to the original **variable**, so changing the original variable to refer to a different string doesn't do anything.  When you change the variable, you're changing which string `foo` refers to, not editing its original string, as that's immutable.

If it's easier to think of, you're passing "what `foo` means" not "`foo` itself", so once that string goes into whatever you're passing it into, it has *no relation* to the original variable.

Comment: Hang on - it *is* a reference to the original string object which is passed... but you can't change the contents of the string, precisely because strings are immutable. It's not an alias to the original *variable*, but that's a different matter. It's worth distinguishing between a variable and its value - `foo` is a variable whose value is a string reference; it's not a string (or a string reference) itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i pass a string as a method parameter, prefixed with the 'ref' keyword it *will* change the original value though, is this some .net trickery?

Comment: @maxp - In that case you're passing a reference to the variable, @Jon - I'll try and make it a bit clearer, didn't realize you could read it that way, give me a min

Comment: @maxp: "ref" is only effective for the duration of the method call - there's no way of aliasing a variable in a more permanent way. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @nick - setting the property of 'InnerHtml' as a string variable prefixed with 'ref' is not legal, and i take it there is nothing similar?

Comment: @Jon - Updated, hopefully that's a bit clearer, feel free to edit further if not.

Comment: @Nick: I've made a couple more edits - check that you agree with them :)

Comment: @Jon - Absolutely, that's 100% clear, what I think of and being able to articulate it clearly don't always go hand in hand, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @maxp - I don't know of a way to do what you're after, you can update `bar.InnerHtml` whenever you want via that property, internally it's not even a string, IIRC it gets transformed into a `LiteralControl` when you set the `InnerHtml`, along with the viewstate setting, you can see this by doing `((LiteralControl)bar.Controls[0]).Text = "zzzzzzz"; //now bar.InnerHtml == "zzzzzzz"`