# Can I make std::string use less memory?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, memory

Before I begin, I need to state that my application uses lots of strings, which are on average quite small, and which do not change once created.

In Visual Studio 2010, I noticed that the capacity of std::string is at least 30. Even if I write `std::string str = "test";`, the capacity of str is 30. The function `str.shrink_to_fit()` does nothing about this although a function with the same name exists for std::vector and works as expected, namely decreasing the capacity so that capacity == size.

1. Why does `std::string::shrink_to_fit()` not work at expected?
2. How can I ensure that the string allocates the least amount of memory?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916358/immutable-strings-vs-stdstring

Comment: You could use a custom allocator for `std::basic_string`. However, doing so will create a string type that is not compatible with `std::string`.

Comment: This sounds like the small buffer optimization with a rather larger small buffer. If it's the small buffer optimization then you can't make it smaller.

Comment: This is probably caused by "short [or small] string optimisation" and unfortunately for you, it's an optimisation for speed rather than space. I doubt that it can be disabled, but I wouldn't mind being wrong.

Comment: Are the values for your strings compile or runtime constant?

Comment: Note that on a 64-bit system, you can't realistically implement `std::basic_string` without at least 24 bytes (3 pointers) 
in the string object itself. It's quite possible this is SSO, and the only space you're wasting is 8 bytes on stack (which could even be wasted anyway for alignment).

Comment: @molbdnilo If implemented correctly, SSO is optimization for **both** space and time. Good optimization uses for small buffer the same space that otherwise would be used for three pointers.

Comment: Here is a summary of the SSO characteristics of various string implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28003328/576911

Comment: @IlyaPopov So I *was* wrong. That's good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Your `std::string` implementation most likely uses some form of the [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring/10319672#10319672) resulting in a fixed size for smaller strings and no effect for `shrink_to_fit`. Note that `shrink_to_fit` is non-binding for the implementation, so this is actually conforming.
2. You could use a `vector<char>` to get more precise memory management, but would loose some of the additional functionality of `std::string`. You could also write your own `string` wrapper which uses a `vector` internally.

Answer (score 1):

One reason that `std::string::shrink_to_fit()` does nothing is that it is not required to by the standard

> *Remarks:* **shrink_to_fit** is a non-binding request to reduce `capacity()` to `size()`. [ Note: The request is non-binding to allow latitude for implementation-specific optimizations. —end note ]

If you want to make sure the string shrinks then you can use the `swap()` trick like

```
std::string(string_to_shrink).swap(string_to_shrink)
```

Another reason this may not work is that the implementer of `std::string` is allowed to implement [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) so you could always have a minimum size of 30 on your implementation.

Comment: The swap trick is essentially what `shrink_to_fit` was intended to replace. I think the issue here is the SSO.

Answer (score 1):

What you observe is a result of SSO (short string optimization), as pointed out by others.

What you could do about it depends on the usage pattern:

- If you strings are parts of one big string, which is typical for parsing, you can use classes like [`std::experimental::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view), GSL [`string_span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/string_span.h), Google's StringPiece, LLVM's [StringRef](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html) etc. which do not store data themselves but only refer to a piece of some other string, while providing interface similar to `std::string`.
- If there are multiple copies of the same strings (especially long ones), it may make sense to use CoW (copy-on-write) strings, where copies share the same buffer using reference counter mechanism until modified. (But be aware of downsides)
- If the strings are very short (just a few chars) it may make sense to write your own specialized class, something in line with [Handling short codes](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/handling-short-codes-part-i/) by Andrzej

Whatever case you chose, it is important to establish good benchmarking procedure to clearly see what effect (if any) you get.

Upd: after rereading the introduction to the question, I think the third approach is the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a lot of small strings in your application then you might want to take a look at fbstring (https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBString.md).