# Need help understanding valid C-strings operations in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I was asked a question on an assignment about stings. The question asked: 
Given the declaration: `char myString[16];`
Which of the following statements is valid? If a statement is invalid, provide the correct syntax.

```
a. strcpy(myString, “Hello the world”);
b. strlen(myString);
c. myString = “Marylane”;
d. cin.getline(myString, 80);
e. cout << myString;
f. if (myString >= “Nice day”)
     cout << myString;
g. myString[6] = ‘t’;
```

The I have been able to compile several of these sections as follows:

```
/*b.*/ int len;
 len = strlen(myString);

/*c.*/ strcpy(myString, “Hello the world”);

/*f.*/ int strTest;
 strTest = strcmp(myString, "Nice day");

 if (strTest < 0)
   cout << myString << endl;
 else 
   { 
   cout << "No Dice" << endl; 
   }
```

I assumed 'g' would be invalid because I thought you could not use a assignment operators, but I got it to compile. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: Why would you not be able to use the assignment operator? In this case, you are simply assigning a raw value to a memory location.

Comment: You can't assign to an array, but you can assign to a single element in the array (unless it is itself an array).

Comment: What would you think would be the proper way to set the seventh character in the string to a `t`?

Comment: The way it is shown above makes sense to me. I just noticed in our book where it said, "Because aggregate operations, such as assignment and comparison, are not allowed on arrays, the following statement is not legal: studentName="Lisa Johnson"; " How is that different from what is above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char myString[16];` is an array. `myString[6] = 't';` assigns character `'t'` to the sixth index of that array. This is a valid operation in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `std::string` to make operations for your strings in your code, and `std::string` is **mutable**. So you can change some parts of your string with basic operations like in your assignment. I would suggest you to read either the documentation or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916394/1867076

Also, you can find some examples to help you in here too: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/821/

Please inform me if this not provides an answer to your question.