# Insert Formatted String to StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string-formatting, stringbuilder

Is there a (system library) way to insert a formatted string to a `StringBuilder` that will be identical to the following?

```
myStringBuilder.Insert(0, string.Format("%02X", someInt));
```

I haven't find any in the [class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: as i know this will work propertly

Comment: @Jon - I was just wondering if there's a library support for that, or should I write as I did.

Comment: But obviously you do have access to the internet and MSDN online, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx. There is no `InsertFormat` method.

Comment: @Pranay Rana - thanks, I know, I meant something like `AppendFormat`

Comment: @Jodrell - That's a fair comment, yet I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: @MByD, perhaps in .Net 5.0 although, I don't recall ever calling `StringBuilder.Insert`, it always seemed more efficient to `Append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringBuilder provides you the method `AppendFormat` which does the append and the format in one call but adds the content in the end of the buffer.

In your specific case since there is no provided .NET framework method which does `InsertFormat` as you wish you either use the method shown above in your question or create an extension method (for example call it InsertFormat) and then use it in your project.

Comment: The extension method is probably the best suggestion here, but I feel this is technically not a good answer because the question specifically stipulates "system library method".

Comment: @Jodrell - No is a legit answer :). BTW why append seems more efficient to you?

Comment: @MByd, internally the string array is some buffer of chars, when you `Append` the new chars are written to the end (if there is not enough space the buffer is extended.) When you `Insert`, a space is made by shifting all the "after" chars up the buffer and the new chars go in the gap. It is possible that the implementation could be some sort of linked list but that sounds too ineffiecient, in general, to be true and I believe that I've read that that is no the case.

Comment: further to previous comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524240/how-does-stringbuilder-work, note the last post http://1024strongoxen.blogspot.com/2010/02/net-40-stringbuilder-implementation.html which suggests it may actually be a linked list now.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension method

```
public static StringBuilder InsertFormat(this StringBuilder sb, string format, params object[] args)
{
    sb.Insert(0, string.Format(format, args)); 
}
```

Then you can write

```
myStringBuilder.InsertFormat("%02X", someInt);
```

Comment: This solution is not a system library method

Comment: Well that's what I currently do pretty much. I wondered if there is a library method though. Thanks!