# Replace all occurrences of a string in given char/byte array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, replace, char

I come from C++ background and was wondering whether in C# exist any magic that would let me to do the following:

```
char[] buf = new char[128*1024*1024];
// filling the arr
buf = buf.ToString().Replace(oldstring, newstring).ToArray();
```

Is there a chance to do it fast (not write all things by hand) and efficient (have one copy of buffer)?

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what is *really* your char array is in code provided, but... 
Use [String[] ctor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx) to construct the string from your char array, and after call replace with desired parameters.

Comment: it's used as (binary / text) file buffer. Suppose you got a really big file, get a piece of it and process the data in a iterative manner. btw calling `string strbuf = new string(buf)` will allocate more memory, it this true?

Comment: Yes, strings are immutable in C#, so it will allocate a new block of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Since strings are immutable in .NET, the most memory efficient way of manipulating them is by using the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9sxk6fy.aspx) class, [which internally treats them as mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564906/how-the-stringbuilder-class-is-implemented-does-it-internally-create-new-string/3564934#3564934).

Here's an example:

```
var buffer = new StringBuilder(128*1024*1024);

// Fill the buffer using the 'StringBuilder.Append' method.
// Examples:
// buffer.Append('E');
// buffer.Append("foo");
// buffer.Append(new char[] { 'A', 'w', 'e', 's', 'o', 'm', 'e' });
// Alternatively you can access the elements of the underlying char array directly
// through 'StringBuilder.Chars' indexer.
// Example:
// buffer.Chars[9] = 'E';

buffer = buffer.Replace(oldstring, newstring);
```

Comment: ToString() generates a copy.  So: no.

Comment: @Hans Passant Mine was just an example. The `StringBuilder` class treats strings as mutable, so the manipulation itself is memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stay with the array (and cannot use something else to start with, e.g. as others suggested a `StringBuilder`), then no. There is no built in, "zero-copy", way to "replace a (sub-)char-array with another (sub-)char-array in a given char-array".