# Is .NET's StringBuilder thread-safe

Tags: .net, thread-safety, stringbuilder

The regular "Thread Safety" section of the MSDN documentation for `StringBuilder` states that:

> ...any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe...

but this statement feels like it has been copied and pasted for almost every class in the Framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

However, these blog posts by Gavin Pugh mention thread-safe behaviours of `StringBuilder`:

http://www.gavpugh.com/2010/03/23/xnac-stringbuilder-to-string-with-no-garbage/

http://www.gavpugh.com/2010/04/01/xnac-avoiding-garbage-when-working-with-stringbuilder/

Additionally, the source of StringBuilder revealed by Reflector, and the accompanying comments 
 in the SSCLI source, also suggest many implementation considerations to ensure thread-safety:

http://labs.developerfusion.co.uk/SourceViewer/browse.aspx?assembly=SSCLI&namespace=System.Text&type=StringBuilder

Does anyone have any more insight into whether a `StringBuilder` instance is safe to share among multiple concurrent threads?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Absolutely not; here's a simple example lifted from 4.0 via reflector:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public StringBuilder Append(char value)
{
    if (this.m_ChunkLength < this.m_ChunkChars.Length)
    {
        this.m_ChunkChars[this.m_ChunkLength++] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Append(value, 1);
    }
    return this;
}
```

The attribute just handles callers, not thread-safety; this is **absolutely** not thread-safe.

Update: looking at the source he references, this is clearly not the current .NET 4.0 code-base (comparing a few methods). Perhaps he is talking about a particular .NET version, or maybe XNA - but it is **not** the case in general. The 4.0 `StringBuilder` does not **have** a `m_currentThread` field, which Gavin's source material uses; there's a hint (an unused constant `ThreadIDField`) that it **used** to exist, but... no longer.

---

If you want a **direct** disproof - run this on 4.0; it will most likely give the wrong length (I've seen a few in the 4k region, a few in the 2k region - it should be exactly 5000), but some other `Append` methods (`Append(char)` for example) tend more likely to throw exceptions, depending on timing:

```
var gate = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var allDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);
int counter = 0;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
ThreadStart work = delegate
{
    // open gate when all 5 threads are running
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) == 5) gate.Set();
    else gate.WaitOne();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) sb.Append("a");

    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter) == 0) allDone.Set();
};
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
    new Thread(work).Start();
}
allDone.WaitOne();
Console.WriteLine(sb.Length);
```

Comment: `String.Builder` up to 3.5 still contains the thread-checking code. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3564934/3205 for more details.

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of the documentation is to give you guarantees. In this case on instance members nothing is guaranteed to be thread-safe and you should treat it as such, therefore relying on external synchronisation methods.

That some things *may be* threadsafe is an *implementation detail* which can and maybe does change from one version of the framework to the next or from one implementation to the next (in fact there are plenty of such details changing in framework versions; Eric Lippert has some posts detailing a few of them). Don't rely on it.

(In other words: Don't write code to an implementation, write it against the interface and contract which is the metadata of the class and its documentation in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#threadSafetyToggle):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.