# Adding string to StringBuilder from async method

Tags: c#, .net, string, asynchronous, task

I have async method that returns string (From web).

```
async Task<string> GetMyDataAsync(int dataId);
```

I have:

```
Task<string>[] tasks = new Task<string>[max];
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = GetMyDataAsync(i);
}
```

How can I append result of each of this tasks to `StringBuilder`?

I would like to know how to do it

A) In order of task creation

B) In order that tasks finish

How can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> A) In order of task creation

```
Task<string>[] tasks = new Task<string>()[max];
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = GetMyDataAsync(i);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
foreach(var task in tasks)
    stringBuilder.Append(task.Result);
```

> B) In order that tasks finish

```
Task<string>[] tasks = new Task<string>()[max];
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = GetMyDataAsync(i).ContinueWith(t => stringBuilder.Append(t.Result));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

If you are inside an `async` method you can also use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` instead of the `Task.WaitAll`.

ATTENTION:

1. `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe: [Is .NET's StringBuilder thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831385/is-nets-stringbuilder-thread-safe)
   ==> you should `lock` inside the `ContinueWith`
2. As pointed out by Matías: You should also check for a successful task completion