# Strings - How do they work?

Tags: java, string

How do `String` objects work in Java? How does term "immutable" exactly apply to string objects? Why don't we see modified string after passing through some method, though we operate on original string object value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't strings be mutable in Java and .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net)

Comment: How did this poorly researched 3 part question get an up-vote?  *"Explanation with examples is appreciated."*  Yes (drily) as are well researched questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

a String has a private final `char[]` . when a new String object is created, the array is also created and filled. it cannot be later accessed [from outside] or modified [actually it can be done with reflection, but we'll leave this aside].

it is "immutable" because once a string is created, its value cannot be changed, a "cow" string will always have the value "cow".

We don't see modified string because it is immutable, the same object will never be changed, no matter what you do with it [besides modifying it with reflection]. so "cow" + " horse" will create a **new** String object, and NOT modify the last object.

if you define:

```
void foo(String arg) {
  arg= arg + " horse";
}
```

and you call:

```
String str = "cow";
foo(str);
```

the `str` where the call is is not modified [since it is the original reference to the same object!] when you changed `arg`, you simply changed it to reference another String object, and did NOT change the actual original object. so `str`, will be the same object, which was not changed, still containing `"cow"`

if you still want to change a String object, you can do it with reflection. However, it is **unadvised** and can have some serious side-affects:

```
    String str = "cow";
    try { 
    Field value = str.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
    Field count = str.getClass().getDeclaredField("count");
    Field hash = str.getClass().getDeclaredField("hash");
    Field offset = str.getClass().getDeclaredField("offset");
    value.setAccessible(true);
    count.setAccessible(true);
    hash.setAccessible(true);
    offset.setAccessible(true);
    char[] newVal = { 'c','o','w',' ','h','o','r','s','e' };
    value.set(str,newVal);
    count.set(str,newVal.length);
    hash.set(str,0);
    offset.set(str,0);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Using cow as an example for your string gets confusing when searching for C.O.W copy on write Java Strings. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Copy-on-write

Answer (score 4):

From the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html):

> The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a String object cannot be changed. The String class has a number of methods, some of which will be discussed below, that appear to modify strings. Since strings are immutable, what these methods really do is create and return a new string that contains the result of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are immutable (state cannot be modified once created). This offers opportunities for optimization. One example is string interning, where string literals are maintained in a string pool and new String objects are only created if the particular string literal doesn't already exist in the pool. If the string literal already exists, a reference is returned. This can only be accomplished because strings are immutable, so you don't have to worry that some object holding a reference will change it.

Methods that appear to modify a string actually return a new instance. One example is string concatenation:

```
String s = "";
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
    s = s + "hi";
}
```

What actually happens internally (the compiler changes it):

```
String s = "";
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append("hi");
    s = sb.toString();
}
```

You can clearly see that new instances are created by the toString method (note that this can be made more efficient by directly using StringBuffers). StringBuffers are mutable, unlike Strings.

Comment: `sb.append("hi")`
Does the "hi" from the statement above get added to string pool?

Answer (score 0):

Every object has *state*. The state of a String object is the array of characters that make up the String, for example, the String "foo" contains the array ['f', 'o', 'o']. Because a String is *immutable*, this array can *never* be changed in any way, shape, or form.

Every method in every class that wants to change a String must instead return a *new* String that represents the altered state of the old String. That is, if you try to reverse "foo" you will get a *new* String object with internal state ['o', 'o', 'f'].

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) link will help you to understand how Java String really works

Now consider the following code -

`String s = "ABC";
s.toLowerCase();`
The method toLowerCase() will not change the data "ABC" that s contains. Instead, a new String object is instantiated and given the data "abc" during its construction. A reference to this String object is returned by the toLowerCase() method. To make the String s contain the data "abc", a different approach is needed.

Again consider the following - `s = s.toLowerCase();`

Now the String s references a new String object that contains "abc". There is nothing in the syntax of the declaration of the class String that enforces it as immutable; rather, none of the String class's methods ever affect the data that a String object contains, thus making it immutable.

I don't really understood your third question. May be providing a chunk of code and telling your problem is a better option. Hope this helps.

You can also look into this [blogpost](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html) for more understanding

[code samples are taken from the wiki. you can also look in there for more information]