# Why String in java is immutable?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are strings immutable in many programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544182/why-are-strings-immutable-in-many-programming-languages)

Why String Class in java is immutable?
Is there any specific reason behind this or this is just an Author's decision?

Comment: Turn the question around: why would it would be desirable for `String` to be mutable?

Answer (score 3):

Immutable strings are a decision that many language writers use. i.e. C# and others. With strings immutable it make a string object inherently thread safe. This allows strings to be used in multithreaded applications without consideration for locks.

Also it allows for changes to the string to branch off the original string in a change list sort of method. This is generally how strings are thought of logically after they are initally constructed.