# Why aren't strings mutable?

Tags: javascript

Arrays are mutable.  I can do this:

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3];

arr[4] = 4;
```

but not this

```
var str = "abcd";

str[4] = "e";
```

This is something I don't find intuitive.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544182/why-are-strings-immutable-in-many-programming-languages

Comment: The real question would be: why on earth are C strings mutable?

Comment: The duplicate Q/A is very one sided.  If it was 100% correct than language designers would make more things immutable.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I think the OPs question is valid. To answer yours, because RAM is mutable: you *initially* get the ability to change whatever you want at the lowest level. It's when you want some features at a higher level that you first want something immutable. Thanks for the link @siledh!

Comment: yea don't forget that software doesn't live in a cloud with fairies and elves, it lives in real hardware.