# How to trim spaces of runtime variable in java?

Tags: java, string

i have following piece of code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class MainDriver{
   public static void main(String aa[]){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        String name;
        System.out.println("enter your name");
        name = reader.nextLine();
        name.trim();
        System.out.println (name);
    }
}
```

And i am wondering about output if i give whitespaces in input

**input**

```
 bayant singh
```

**output**

```
 bayant singh
```

So why `name.trim;` is not working here?As i am guessing output to be

```
bayantsingh //no spaces
```

Comment: [`String#trim()` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis please tell me where i can find javadoc

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis docs.oracle.com

Answer (score 8):

trim removes whitespaces at either end of the string. to remove all spaces try:

```
name = name.replace(" ","");
```

for all whitespace of any kind it has been pointed out to me you can use the regex:

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that Strings are immutable, which means its methods can't edit its state (stored characters) but instead they create new updated String instance. So

```
name.trim();
```

creates and returns new trimmed String which you are ignoring because you are not storing result of this method anywhere. If you want `name` reference to hold trimmed String you should use

```
name = name.trim();
```

Your second problem is that if you want to change `" bayant singh"` to `"bayantsingh"` you shouldn't use `trim` method because removes only spaces only at start and end of your String.
If you want to remove all spaces you should use

```
name = name.replace(" ","");
```

Comment: this is correct for trim, not correct for what he wants. trim does not remove spaces in between words, only at the beginning and ending

Comment: @AdamYost Yes, I was in the middle of editing my answer. I am not sure why I didn't described it sooner (maybe OP added that part later but before 5 min grace time so this change is not in edit history).

Comment: @pshemo String's methods don't change its state because of pass by value nature.is it so?

Comment: @Bayant_singh This things are not related since all methods are pass-by-value (there is no pass-by-reference in Java). If you pass some value to method you can change state of instance on which you invoked this method. That is how setters work. [Strings are meant to be immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9544182/1393766). If you need more informations about immutability you can find many good questions explaining it like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects

Answer (score 1):

If you want replace all spaces use .replaceAll()

```
name = name.replace(" ",""); // replace first space
name = name.replaceAll(" ",""); // replace all spaces in the string
```

Comment: `name.replace(" ","")` will replace all spaces, not just first. Difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` is that it doesn't take regex as searched parameter but literal.