# C#: string.Trim() not removing white spaces

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, trim

I have a prompt asking user to enter a date (in a specific format).  Then I trim the string, however if the there was an extra space when I hit 'Enter' in the prompt box, the string still comes out with an extra space after the trim.  I'll post my prompt box code too.  My string is: Jul 29, 2015 1:32:01 PM PDT  and Jul 30, 2015 12:34:27 PM PDT

```
    string afterpromptvalue = Prompt.ShowDialog("Enter earliest Date and Time", "Unshipped Orders");
                    afterpromptvalue.Trim();
                    string beforepromptvalue = Prompt.ShowDialog("Enter latest Date and Time", "Unshipped Orders");
                    beforepromptvalue.Trim();

 string format = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt PDT";

            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            afterpromptvalue.Trim();
            beforepromptvalue.Trim();


            DateTime createdAfter = DateTime.ParseExact(afterpromptvalue, format, provider);



            DateTime createdBefore = DateTime.ParseExact(beforepromptvalue, format, provider);

public static class Prompt
{
    public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
    {
        Form prompt = new Form();
        prompt.Width = 500;
        prompt.Height = 150;
        prompt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        prompt.Text = caption;
        prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top=20, Text=text };
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top=50, Width=400 };
        Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left=350, Width=100, Top=70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

        return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: The trim method returns a string you are aware of that right ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \`String.Trim()\` not trim the object itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190818/why-does-string-trim-not-trim-the-object-itself)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`string.Trim` returns a new string. It does not update the existing variable.

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

The proper syntax for your code would be:

`afterpromptvalue = afterpromptvalue.Trim();`

Answer (score 2):

Calling Trim() on a string doesn't change the string itself.  It **returns** the string trimmed.

In C#, strings aren't changeable. All you can do to a string is assign a new string to it, calling methods on a string can not change the original string unless you assign the return value to the string object in question.

For example, change:

```
afterpromptvalue.Trim();
```

To:

```
afterpromptvalue = afterpromptvalue.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this maybe ;)

```
afterpromptvalue = afterpromptvalue.Trim();
beforepromptvalue = beforepromptvalue.Trim();
```

And read this :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d4tt83f9(v=VS.110).aspx

Maybe this quote from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Immutability) is interesting for you

> **Immutability and the StringBuilder class**
>
> A String object is called
> immutable (read-only), because its value cannot be modified after it
> has been created. Methods that appear to modify a String object
> actually return a new String object that contains the modification.