# Inverse Count Issue C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, count, inverse

Not Quite what the title suggests, what i need is a way to count a string backwards like

```
string i = "3027"
i[0] = label1.Text
```

Result = 7 not 3 is there a way?

not sure if you need my code or not its not really important.

Comment: [.SUBSTRING()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You want the whole string reversed or only the last element in the string?

Answer (score 5):

You can reverse the string using a number of approaches including

```
public static string ReverseString(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/reverse-string

then access the portion of the reversed string that you are interested in.

Note that you *cannot* assign to `i[0]` as shown in your example code because [strings are immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) in C# ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net)).  If you want to construct a string a bit at a time, it is often most efficient to use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: _Cannot_ **assign** `i[0]`. - access confused me for a second