# How do I unstring in python

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a text encryptionish program that will change the letters in text to a different ordred alphabet, however a = key[1](Key being the name of the rearanged alphabet) but it dosn't work because key[1] can't be assigned to a litteral, any ideas of how to get arround this.

Comment: If you provided some code that illustrated the problem, it would be a lot easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

So `key` is your rearranged alphabet, and `ALPHA` is the normal alphabet.

```
ALPHA = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
key = 'zwlsqpugxackmirnhfdvbjoeyt'
msg = 'secretmessage'
code = []

for i in msg:
    code.append(key[ALPHA.index(i)])

print(''.join(code))
```

Make the string after encoding, rather than during encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python, and many other languages, are immutable, [because reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net).

What you need is to create a new string, replacing characters as needed.

For byte strings (that in Python are plain byte arrays) there's [`.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). It takes a 256-byte string that describes how to replace each possible byte.

For Unicode strings `.translate` takes a map which is a bit more convenient but still maybe cumbersome:

```
unicode('foo bar').translate({ord('f'): u'F', ord('b'): u'B'})
```

In general case, something like this should work:

```
def transform_char(char):
  # shift a characte 3 positions forward
  return chr(ord(char) + 3)

def transform(source_string):
  return ''.join(transform_char(c) for c in source_string)
```

What happens in `transform`? It generates a list of transformed characters (`[transform_char(c) for c in source_string]`) is called a "list comprehension". This list contains a transformed character for each character in `source_string`. Then all elements of this list are efficiently `join`ed together by placing an empty string `''` between them.

I hope it's enough for you now.