# Why does C# string have a title "Immutable" if to compare it with F# analogue?

Tags: c#, f#, heap-memory, immutability

I have read the older topics like those ones:

- [Why can't strings be mutable in Java and .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net)
- [Why .NET String is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable#)

But, I can't understand the meaning of the word `immutable`, if to compare it with the F# analogue:

```
open System
let data = "London"
data <- "123"
Console.WriteLine data
```

This one won't compile due the next reason:

> error FS0027: This value is not mutable. Consider using the mutable
>   keyword, e.g. 'let mutable data = expression'.

So... If to compare the F# behaviour with the C# one, seems to be F# has the real meaning of immutability or I don't understand the real meaning of this term...

Let's look at the C# variant:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = "London";
        a = "123";
        System.Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

The output will be: `123`.

Let's take information from the next article: [Why are the strings immutable in .NET?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/230635/why-string-are-immutable-in-dotnet/)

[image: String appending]

Honestly, if to look at this picture and compare it with the F# variant, I can't see the immutability... But also, I understand, that over 100+ people at SO (questions were published at the top of this question) can't be wrong and give the wrong name for such meaning.

Please, tell me why has been the C# string called `immutable`, if I can change its value? And if to compare it with the F# sample, the results are different for the single meaning.

Comment: You can't change the value of an existing string, a new string is allocated with the new value. As the [string documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) says, _"Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, **although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this.**"_

Comment: You can't change its value as seen in your last illustration were not the original string is modified but a new copy is created.

Comment: `string` instances are immutable, F# let bindings are immutable but c# local variables are not.

Comment: @Neverlands just a quick note to the examples, `data = "123"` in 2nd case in F# is not the same as `a = "123"` in the C# variant - it's more like `a == "123"`, so it's a test, producing a bool, which then gets discarded. It has little to do with the immutability.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan I see, thanks for your comment, I shall remove that part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing the immutability of the variable in F# with the immutability of the object in C#.

In C#, you can change which object representing a string a variable is pointing at. But you can't change anything about that object, hence the object is immutable.

In F#, you cannot change which value a variable has, so the variable is also immutable.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that C#'s variable only references a string object, but the F# variable is the string object itself? (I've never worked in F#)

Comment: I have only passing familiarity with F#, but according to MSDN F#'s string is the same old System.string so the F# variable would also hold a reference to an object. The difference in F# being that you can't change which object is being referenced, similar to a `const string` or readonly field in C#. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings

Comment: It should be worth noting that in the first F# case, the code will compile and work like the C# case if data is declared like so: `let mutable data = "London"`. So the mutability exception is due to the the fact that the *variable* data is immutable, which of course is in line with what you say in your answer.